# Activity has leaked window that was originally added

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dialog

What is this error, and why does it happen?

```
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850): Activity com.mypkg.myP has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44c46ff0 that was originally added here
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ccom.mypkg.myP has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44c46ff0 that was originally added here
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:231)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.mypkg.myP$PreparePairingLinkageData.onPreExecute(viewP.java:183)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.mypkg.myP.onCreate(viewP.java:94)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The other classic is when orientation changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre

Answer (score 1715, accepted):

You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.

**[EDIT]**

This question is one of the top search on google for android developer,
therefore Adding few important points from comments, which might be more helpful for future investigator without going in depth of comment conversation.

**Answer 1** :

> You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.

**Answer 2**

> This error can be a little misleading in some circumstances (although
>   the answer is still completely accurate) - i.e. in my case an
>   unhandled Exception was thrown in an AsyncTask, which caused the
>   Activity to shutdown, then an open progressdialog caused this
>   Exception.. so the 'real' exception was a little earlier in the log

**Answer 3**

> Call dismiss() on the Dialog instance you created before exiting your
>   Activity, e.g. in onPause() or onDestroy()

Comment: @Override
    public void onStop() { if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
    }}

Comment: Even after 8 years this is still relevant! I got the exception because the activity was closed while it was trying to display my AlertDialog (so Answer 2). In the end I found out that the app was adding a "null" object to the scene (shouldn't have happened but it did) but it didn't give an extra exception for it and the whole thing was masked by the "leaked window" exception instead.

Comment: Is it possible to scan for all open dialogs and close them all in the onStop()? I generate dialogs in a ListView when clicking on items. I am not sure how to retrieve their reference from the onStop.

Comment: Answer 3 is the best solution. worked greatly for me. Thanks kaze, Alex!!

Comment: additional tip if you are displaying the dialog in a loop ensure the loop is exited after activity finish

Comment: Call dismiss() on the Dialog instance you created before exiting your Activity. solved my problem. So always call dismiss before exiting activity

Comment: Very miss leading. After identifying the error causing the activity to close it stoped

Comment: This answer is still valid till this date. It worked like charm! Thanks... The error in logcat showed a link that made me go to the line of code that had alertDialog.show();

Comment: Answer 2 worked for me. it was misleading. actual error was something else

Comment: In the case that answer 3 wanting to handle, the StackTrace is not the code that trigger the exception but where the dialog beening shown. It is very misleading.

Answer (score 424):

The solution is to call `dismiss()` on the `Dialog` you created in `viewP.java:183` before exiting the `Activity`, e.g. in `onPause()`. All `Window`s&`Dialog`s should be closed before leaving an `Activity`.

Comment: So when the user rotates the phone, all dialogs should be dismissed?? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @LarsH as you can see, my answer was written more than 7 years ago, and this was definitely true at that time. I no longer work with Android, but based on what I see in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), it might still be the case, but Android has come a long way since (introduced Fragments just to name one), so it is probably easier now.

Answer (score 115):

If you are using `AsyncTask`, probably that log message can be deceptive. If you look up in your log, you might find another error, probably one in your `doInBackground()` method of your `AsyncTask`, that is making your current `Activity` to blow up, and thus once the `AsyncTask` comes back.. well, you know the rest. Some other users already explained that here :-)

Comment: Sometimes in that case I am not able to see the real exception. To find the real exception just comment out the progressDialog.show() and run the app again.. now you see it.

Comment: Hi folks! As mentioned above by @Stuck I am not able to see the real exception as well, What I did? I tracked it using breaking points and I discovered that I was using a reference of an Application class inside the method `doInBackground` of the `AsyncTask` class but without declare it in the `AndroidManifest` file using the property `android:name` like this: `android:name="my.package.MyApplicationClass"`. A good practice when using `AsyncTask` it is always remember to instantiate your alert inside the method `onPreExecute` and dismissing it on `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 80):

I triggered this error by mistakenly calling `hide()` instead of `dismiss()` on an `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me. Also, calling hide() and then setting the dialog to null is not a valid alternative either.

Comment: I would really know the issue behind this. But calling dismiss() helped me!

Answer (score 65):

You can get this exception by just a simple/dumb mistake, by (for example) accidentally calling `finish()` after having displayed an `AlertDialog`, if you miss a break call statement in a switch statement...

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.new_button:
            openMyAlertDialog();
            break; <-- If you forget this the finish() method below 
                       will be called while the dialog is showing!
        case R.id.exit_button:
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
```

The `finish()` method will close the `Activity`, but the `AlertDialog` is still displaying!

So when you're staring intently at the code, looking for bad threading issues or complex coding and such, don't lose sight of the forest for the trees.  Sometimes it can be just something as simple and dumb as a missing break statement.  :)

Comment: More or less exactly my issue. Called finish in onError after dialog created, not in onClick for the dismiss button.

Answer (score 65):

The answers to this question were all correct, but a little confusing for me to actually understand why. After playing around for around 2 hours the reason to this error (in my case) hit me:

You already know, from reading other answers, that the has `X has leaked window DecorView@d9e6131[]` error means a dialog was open when your app closed. But why?

**It could be, that your app crashed for some other reason while your dialog was open**

This lead to your app closing because of some bug in your code, which lead to the dialog remaining open at the same time as your app closed due to the other error.

**So, look through your logical. Solve the first error, and then the second error will solve itself[image]**

**One error causes another, which causes another, like DOMINOS!**

Comment: Can't believe this has only one upvote.. or we are just really bad at programming hahaha I also liked your domino analogy

Comment: Solve the first error and the second error **will not occur**.
This analogy helped me.

Comment: This is not completely right, instances like phone rotation can also cause "activity" rotation to happen.

Comment: Excellent explanation (y)

Answer (score 39):

This problem arises when trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.

I just solved this problem just by writing down the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if ( progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing() ){
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

Basically, from which class you started progressDialog, override onDestroy method and do this way. It solved "Activity has leaked window" problem.

Comment: onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called. Better to put that code in onPause or onStop

Answer (score 22):

I recently faced the same issue.

The reason behind this issue is that the activity being closed before the dialog is dismissed. 
There are various reasons for the above to happen. The ones mentioned in the posts above are also correct.

I got into a situation, because in the thread, I was calling a function which was throwing exception. Because of which the window was being dismissed and hence the exception.

Answer (score 20):

This could help.

```
if (! isFinishing()) {

    dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: Among hundreds of similar answers there is no one showing how to check if windows exists. So you save me some time finding the way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Dismiss the dialog when activity destroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: if pDialog is null this will throw an error as you are querying the state of the null dialog

Comment: no it won't @JonDunn, because Java will not process the second boolean if the first one is false

Answer (score 11):

I had the same obscure error message and had no idea why. Given clues from the previous answers, I changed my non-GUI calls to mDialog.finish() to be mDialog.dismiss() and the errors disappeared. This wasn't affecting my widget's behavior but it was disconcerting and could well have been flagging an important memory leak.

Comment: Noticed that i was doing a mDialog.hide() before the finish() call. Changing it to mDialog.dismiss() did the trick.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem and found this page, and while my situation was different I called `finish` from a `if` block before it defined the alert box.

So, simply calling `dismiss` wouldn't work (as it hasn't been made yet) but after reading *Alex Volovoy's* answer and realizing it was the alert box causing it. I tried to add a return statement right after the finish inside that `if` block and that fixed the issue.

I thought once you called finish it stopped everything and finished right there, but it doesn't. It seem to go to the end of the block of code it's in then finishes.

So, if you want to implement a situation where sometimes it'll finish before doing some code you do gotta put a return statement right after the finish or it'll keep on going and and act like the finish was called at the end of the block of code not where you called it. Which is why I was getting all those weird errors.

```
private picked(File aDirectory){
     if(aDirectory.length()==0){
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent()); 
        finish(); 
        return;
    }
     AlertDialog.Builder alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(this); // Start dialog builder
     alert
        .setTitle("Question")
        .setMessage("Do you want to open that file?"+aDirectory.getName());
    alert
        .setPositiveButton("OK", okButtonListener)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", cancelButtonListener);
    alert.show();
}
```

If you don't put the return right after I called finish in there, it will act as if you have called it after the `alert.show();` and hence it would say that the window is leaked by finishing just after you made the dialog appear, even though that's not the case, it still think it is.

I thought I'd add this as here as this shows the finish command acted differently then I thought it did and I'd guess there are other people who think the same as I did before I discovered this.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting these logs in my video player application. These messages were thrown while the video player was closed. Interestingly, I used to get these logs once in a few runs in a random manner. Also my application does not involve in any `progressdialog`. Finally, I got around this issue with the below implementation.

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    Log.v("MediaVideo", "onPause");
    super.onPause();
    this.mVideoView.pause();
    this.mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    Log.v("MediaVideo", "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    Log.v("MediaVideo", "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    this.mVideoView.resume();
}
```

Override the `OnPause` with call to `mVideoView.pause()` and the set `visibility` to `GONE`. This way I could resolve the "`Activity has leaked window`" log error issue.

Comment: i also facing same problem. i added your these lines of code in my code but it didn't work and gives the same error "android.view.WindowLeaked that was originally added" and also not play the video and gives "Video cannot be played"

Answer (score 10):

Generally this issue occurs due to progress dialog : you can solve this by using any one of the following method in your activity:

```
 // 1):
          @Override
                protected void onPause() {
                    super.onPause();
                    if ( yourProgressDialog!=null && yourProgressDialog.isShowing() )
                  {
                        yourProgressDialog.cancel();
                    }
                }

       // 2) :
         @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                if ( yourProgressDialog!=null && yourProgressDialog.isShowing()
               {
                    yourProgressDialog.cancel();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 10):

here is a solution when you **do want to dismiss** AlertDialog but **do not want to keep a reference** to it inside activity.

solution requires you to have **androidx.lifecycle** dependency in your project (i believe at the moment of the comment it's a common requirement)

this lets you to delegate dialog's dismiss to external object (observer), and you dont need to care about it anymore, because it's auto-unsubscribed when activity dies. (here is proof: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/issues/5).

so, the observer keeps the reference to dialog, and activity keeps reference to observer. when "onPause" happens - observer dismisses the dialog, and when "onDestroy" happens - activity removes observer, so no leak happens (well, at least i dont see error in logcat anymore)

```kotlin
// observer
class DialogDismissLifecycleObserver( private var dialog: AlertDialog? ) : LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun onPause() {
        dialog?.dismiss()
        dialog = null
    }
}
// activity code
private fun showDialog() {
        if( isDestroyed || isFinishing ) return
        val dialog = AlertDialog
            .Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme)
            // dialog setup skipped
            .create()
        lifecycle.addObserver( DialogDismissLifecycleObserver( dialog ) )
        dialog.show()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is not the answer to the question but it's relevant to the topic.

If the activity has defined an attribute in the Manifest

```
 android:noHistory="true"
```

then after executing onPause(), the context of activity is lost. So all the view's using *this* context might give this error.

Comment: Can you relate anything similar for `progessdialog.show()` .. and `progressdialog.hide()` in  `asynctask` of the same activity instead of `onPause()` from `activity` ?? 
have a look at my problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332880/activity-has-leaked-window-while-using-volley

Comment: its working for me perfectly :
android:noHistory="true"

Answer (score 6):

Not only try to show an alert but it can also be invoked when you finish a particular instance of activity and try to start new activity/service or try to stop it.

**Example:**

```
OldActivity instance;

    oncreate() {
       instance=this;
    }
    instance.finish();
    instance.startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_MAIN).setClass(instance, NewActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
public class Sample extends Activity(){
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle instance){

}
 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
      progressdialog.dismiss(); // try this
    }

}
```

Comment: `progressdialog.dismiss();` this can create NullPointerException.

Answer (score 5):

The "`Activity has leaked window that was originally added...`" error occurs when you try show an alert after the `Activity` is effectively `finished`.

You have two options AFAIK:

1. Rethink the login of your alert: call `dismiss()` on the `dialog` before actually exiting your activity.
2. Put the `dialog` in a different thread and run it on that `thread` (independent of the current `activity`).

Answer (score 5):

Had the problem where I finished an Activity when a ProgressDialog was still shown.

So first hide the Dialog and then finish the activity.

Answer (score 5):

This can be if you have an error at `doInBackground()` function and have this code.

Try to add dialog at last. At first check and fix `doInBackground()` function

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
     super.onPreExecute();
     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateAccount.this);
     pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
     pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
     pDialog.setCancelable(true);
     pDialog.show();

 }

 protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
     ERROR CAN BE IS HERE
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
     // dismiss the dialog once done
     pDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me when i am using `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncTask`. Actually i am using `hide()` method in `onPostExecute`. Based on the answer of @Alex Volovoy i need to use `dismiss()` with `ProgressDialog` to remove it in onPostExecute and its done.

```
progressDialog.hide(); // Don't use it, it gives error

progressDialog.dismiss(); // Use it
```

Comment: This is not really the full answer.  There are two ways to leak a dialog.  

1) If you have an `AsyncTask` and you show the `Dialog`, then something happens which makes the `Activity` call `onPause()` (maybe some logic in your AsyncTask itself, like a listener, then it will leak. 

2) As mentioned above, the`Dialog` which was created with that `Activity` `Context` is never dismissed and the `Activity` moves on.

Answer (score 5):

Might it help to someone who visit this question.

You should check safe condition for activity and dialog before `show()` and `dismiss()` dialog.

Add below condition before showing dialog

```
    if (!isFinishing && !isDestroyed && !dialog.isShowing) {
         dialog.show()
    }
```

Add below condition before dismiss dialog

```
    if (!isFinishing && !isDestroyed && dialog.isShowing) {
         dialog.dismiss()
    }
```

- `isFinishing` and `isDestroyed` will give surety about activity(from where `Dialog` is initiated) is not in  `isFinishing` or `isDestroyed` state. Sometimes we try to open Dialog when dialog hosting activity is going to destroy and we facing **"leaked window"** issue
- `dialog.isShowing` to check dialog state before `show()` or `dismiss()` dialog.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make `Progressdialog` object in `onPreExecute` method of `AsyncTask` and you should `dismiss` it on `onPostExecute` method.

Answer (score 4):

**Best solution is just add dialog in try catch and dismiss dialog when exception occur**

> Just use below code

```
 try {
        dialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: is not dialog will be null after called finished ?, i think `dialog.dismiss()` will produce error too

Comment: Exception is already occurred in your case. And you advice call dismiss method in catch block? For what purpose?!

Answer (score 4):

Best solution is put this before showing `progressbar` or `progressDialog`

```
if (getApplicationContext().getWindow().getDecorView().isShown()) {

  //Show Your Progress Dialog

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I have Dialog.show() after response from the HTTP call and when in the meantime I rotate the screen Activity is detached but it seems to have isShown == true before Dialog.show() and then Dialog crashes in spite of this check

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the reason was that I forgot to include a permission in the Android manifest file.

How did I find out? Well, just like @Bobby says in a comment beneath the accepted answer, just scroll further up to your logs and you'll see the first reason or event that really threw the Exception. Apparently, the message "Activity has leaked window that was originally added" is only an Exception that resulted from whatever the first Exception is.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code , it will work any time you will dismiss the progress dialogue and it will see whether its instance is available or not.

```
try {
        if (null != progressDialog && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Window leaked exceptions have two reasons:

1) showing the dialog when Activity Context doesn't exists, to solve this you should show the dialog only you are sure Activity exists:

```
if(getActivity()!= null && !getActivity().isFinishing()){
        Dialog.show();
}
```

2) not dismiss the dialog appropriately, to solve use this code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if ( Dialog!=null && Dialog.isShowing() ){
        Dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Got this error when trying to display a Toast from Background thread.
It was solved by running the UI related code on the UI thread

Answer (score 2):

I have another solution for this, and would like to know if it seems valid to you: instead of dismissing in the onDestroy, which seems to be the leading solution, I'm extending ProgressDialog...

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

  private boolean isDismissed;

  public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    dismiss();
  }

  @Override
  public void dismiss() {
    if (isDismissed) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      super.dismiss();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // ignore
    }
    isDismissed = true;
  }
```

This is preferable, AFAIC, because you don't have to hold the progress dialog as a member, just fire(show) and forget

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (mActivity != null && !mActivity.isFinishing() && mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

dismiss progressBar before activity destroyed

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        try {
            if (progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Other that hiding your dialog, dismiss it instead.

Replace `.hide()` with `.dismiss()`

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your activity is not closing unexpectedly due to some exceptions raised somewhere in your code. Generally it happens in async task when activity faces force closure in doinBackground method and then asynctask returns to onPostexecute method.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same kind of problem. the error was not in the `Dialog` but in a `EditText`. I was trying to change the value of the `Edittext` inside of a `Assynctask`. the only away i could solve was creating a new `runnable`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
       ...        
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter the WindowLeaked problem when run monkey test.The logcat is below.

```
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ListMenuDecorView@4334fd40 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myapp.MyActivity has leaked window android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ListMenuDecorView@4334fd40 that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:312)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
            at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.openPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1150)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUpPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1469)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:919)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:913)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2009)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3929)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3420)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4528)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4506)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4610)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Activity is AppCompatActivity.And I resovled it with the below code in the Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // added by sunhang : intercept menu key to resove a WindowLeaked error in monkey-test.
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue according to me is you are trying to call a dialog right after an activity is getting finished so according me what you can do is give some delay using Handler and you issue will be solved for eg:

```
 Handler handler=new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     dialog.show();
                     //or
                     dialog.dismiss();

                }
            },100);
```

Comment: Yes, solution used in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676412/leaked-window-when-exit-app-through-popup-menu

Answer (score 1):

I was using Jetpack Compose and no dialogues so most of these answers were not applicable to me. It turned out that I was accessing out of range array index in a **Kotlin coroutine**.
I wrapped all the coroutine calls in `try` and `catch`.

```kotlin
try {
     viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
     ....
     }
} catch (e: Exception) {
     Log.e("Exception: ", e.message.toString())
}
```

And finally found the error (or should I say my mistake :P).

Answer (score 0):

I was using a dialog `onError of a Video Player, and instead of going crazy (I've tested all of these solutions)

I've opted for `DialogFragment` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html.

You can return the builder creation in an inner `DialogFragment` class, just override `onCreateDialog`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem for some time but  I realized it's not because of `dialog` in my case it's because of `ActionMode`. So if you are trying to finish activity when an `ActionMode` is open it will cause this problem. In your activity's `onPause` finish the action mode.

```
 private ActionMode actionMode;

 @Override
 public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    actionMode = mode;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (actionMode != null) actionMode.finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to call 
           this.dialog.show . (Activity)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used `findViewById` in activity instead of `dialog.findViewById` and set afterwards an `OnClickListener` on a `null` instance and that probably caused the original error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with LiveData, when updating value instead of using `liveData.value = someValue` try to do `liveData.postValue(someValue)`

Answer (score 0):

I am making a scientific app that is already close to 45 thousand lines and I use asynchronous tasks in order to be able to interrupt long tasks, if so desired, with a certain click of the user.

Thus, there is a responsive user interface and sometimes a long task in parallel.

When the long task is over, I need to run a routine that manages the user interface.

So, at the end of an asynchronous task, I do a following action that involves the interface, which cannot be performed directly, otherwise it gives an error. So I use

```
this.runOnUiThread(Runnable { x(...)})   // Kotlin
```

Many times, this error occurs in some point of function `x`.

If function `x` was called outside a thread

```
              x(...)  // Kotlin
```

`Android Studio` would show a call stack with the error line and one easily could fix the problem in few minutes.

As my source code is tamed, and there is no serious structural problem (many answers above describe this kind of errors), the reason for this scary error message is more gross and less important.

It's just any fool mistake in this  execution linked to a thread (like, for example, accessing a vector beyond the defined length), as in this schematic example:

```
           var i = 10                  // Kotlin
           ...
           var arr = Array(5){""}       
           var element = arr[i]       // 10 > 5, it's a index overflow
```

Regarding this stupid error,  `Android Studio` unfortunately doesn't point to it.

I even consider it a bug, because `Android Studio` knows that there is an error, where it is located, but, for some unknown reason, it gets lost and gives a random message, totally disconnected from the problem, i.e, a weird message with no hint showing up.

The solution: Have a lot of patience to run step by step in the debugger until reaching the error line, which `Android Studio` refused to provide.

This has happened to me several times and I guess it's an extremely common mistake on *Android* projects. I had never before given this kind of error to me before I used threads.

Nobody is infallible and we are liable to make small mistakes. In this case, you cannot count on the direct help of `Android Studio` to discover where is your error!

Answer (score 0):

如果只是处理`Dialog`在`Acticity.onConfigurationChanged`出现的问题

If you just deal with the problem of `Dialog` in `Activity.onConfigurationChanged`

```kotlin
//若`AndroidManifest.xml`中已经配置了`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"`则不需要设置该项
//If `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"` has been configured in `AndroidManifest.xml`, you do not need to set this item
Acticity/Context.registerComponentCallbacks(object : ComponentCallbacks {
    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        dialog?.dismiss()
    }
    override fun onLowMemory() {
    }
})
```

在`onDestroy`中销毁更保险点

It is safer to destroy in `on Destroy`

```kotlin
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    DialogManager.dismiss()
}
```

Maybe this is useful for you  https://github.com/javakam/DialogManager

Comment: f you only deal Dialogin Acticity.onConfigurationChanged(with the problem of If you just deal of problems Dialogin Activity.onConfigurationChanged)

Acticity/Context.registerComponentCallbacks(object : ComponentCallbacks {
    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        dialog?.dismiss()
    }
    override fun onLowMemory() {
    }
})
In onDestroythe destruction of safer points (It IS SAFER to the destroy in on Destroy)

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    DialogManager.dismiss()
}
My Project https://github.com/javakam/DialogManager

Answer (score 0):

A only answer is

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        exit_popup();
       // super.onBackPressed(); remove this line

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this bottomSheetDialog.dismiss() the dialog before the finesh() of the activity

```
  startActivity(Intent(this, Activity::class.java))
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
        finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Much later than the previous answers, in 2022 where people use Kotlin, we also get the error when Kotlin coroutine tries to modify a popup window from the wrong (non-Main) coroutine context.

Produces error:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
    someCodeThatNeedsOtherContext()
    someViewBinding.someAttribute = someValue // We get the error here
}
```

Does not produce error:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
    someCodeThatNeedsOtherContext()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{
        someViewBinding.someAttribute = someValue // No error here
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `withContext()` to change context instead of `CoroutineScope()` factory function.

Comment: Ok. Show me how. :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a database operation inside the dialog method, that caused the *Activity* to blow up.

Probably at times this log message can be deceptive.

```
    private fun showDialog() {
        val customDialog = Dialog(requireActivity())
        customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)
        customDialog.window?.setLayout(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        val btnGenerate = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnGenerate) as TextView
        val etScheduleNumber = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.etScheduleNo) as AutoCompleteTextView
        val etTripNumber = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.etTripNumber) as AutoCompleteTextView

        viewModel.getBreakdownScheduleNumbers { scheduleNumberList->
            val adapter = CustomAdapter(requireContext(),
                scheduleNumberList as ArrayList<String>)
            etScheduleNumber.setAdapter(adapter)
        }

        btnGenerate.setOnClickListener {

        }
        customDialog.show()
    }
```