# How to set the Background Color of a View in onRestoreInstanceState()

Tags: android, view, background-color, oncreate

I'm currently trying to learn to work with Views and states.  I'm normally able to set its color in functions like in the following:

```
    View mColorRegion = findViewById(R.id.color_region);
    mColorRegion.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

However, I can't seem to be able to set the color in an **onRestoreInstanceState()**, as

```
     mColorRegion.setBackgroundColor(savedInstanceState.getInt("color"));
```

However, working with the same View as a TextView, I'm able to restore text as in the following:

```
    TextView mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.color_region);
    mText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text");
```

What's the difference, and how I can set the background color in **onRestoreInstanceState()**?

---

EDIT:  Since the original post, I've noticed two things:

1) `mColorRegion.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN)` doesn't seem to work in **onCreate()** either.

2) Even though the following function correctly changes the View color when a button is pressed, it doesn't work if I call it directly from **onRestoreInstanceState()**:

```
    public void centerButton1(View clickedButton) {
        mColorRegion.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
```

Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

So I found a "half-solution".  If you add the following line to *AndroidManifest.xml*, it will preserve the color during orientation changes:

```
     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

However, this still doesn't answer why I can set the text but not the color in **onRetoreInstanceState()** or **onCreate()**...

Answer (score 0):

Many people frown upon using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`, like [Google's Dianne Hackborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335665/avoid-reloading-activity-with-asynctask-in-orientation-change-in-android/5336057#5336057). For one, It will make the process of switching between multiple layouts for your app very difficult (for example, if you want one layout for landscape, and one for portrait) since you'll have to do all of the work that Android normally does automatically for you, in **onConfigurationChanged()**.

Anyway, I also had this sort of problem. I was creating a DialogPreference, and upon rotation I couldn't change the progress of a *SeekBar* in **onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceBundle)**...so this is what I suggest if you cannot use **onCreate(savedInstanceBundle)** or **onActivityCreated(savedInstanceBundle)** (for fragments) to restore the state of your view objects:

**1)** Make a private class member called "mRestoredBGColor",

`private int mRestoredBGColor = -1;`

**2)** In **onRestoreInstanceState():**

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       mRestoredBGColor = savedInstanceState.getInt("key_you_used_in_onSaveInstanceState");
}
```

**3)** Then in **onResume()**, because onRestoreInstanceState() is called after onStart(), but before onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   if(mColorRegion != null && mRestoredBGColor != -1){
       mColorRegion.setBackgroundColor(mRestoredBGColor);
       mRestoredBGColor = -1; //to make sure it only sets this once per rotation.
   }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody. I believe there is always another way (except when you want quickly rotating WebViews...) than using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`.