# Retained Fragment Not Retained

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview, android-orientation

I have a simple layout containing a VideoView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:gravity="center" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `Activity` that uses this layout creates a `Fragment` to start the VideoView

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
            createNewWorkerFragment();
    }

        private void createNewWorkerFragment() {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment workerFragment = (VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment.Name);
            if (workerFragment == null) {
                workerFragment = new VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                               .add(workerFragment, VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment.Name)
                               .commit();
            }
        }
}
```

The `VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment` is as follows:

```
public class VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment extends Fragment {

     public static String Name = "VideoPlayerActivityWorker";
     private VideoView mVideoPlayer;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setRetainInstance(true);
         mVideoPlayer = (VideoView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
         mVideoPlayer.setVideoPath(mActivity.getIntent().getExtras().getString("path"));
         MediaController controller = new MediaController(mActivity);
         controller.setAnchorView(mVideoPlayer);
         mVideoPlayer.setMediaController(controller);
         mVideoPlayer.requestFocus();
         mVideoPlayer.start();
     }

     @Override
     public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
     }

     @Override
     public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mActivity = null;
     }
}
```

This is the issue I'm having, when the `VideoPlayerActivity` starts the `VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment` is created and the `VideoView` starts playing, however when I rotate the device the video stops and will not play, the entire `View` seems gone from the layout. Due to `setRetainInstance(true);` I thought that the `VideoView` would continue to play. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? I have used this pattern elsewhere (not with a `VideoView`) and it successfully allows rotation to happen.

I am unwilling to use the `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` or similar methods, I would like to handle the orientation change with `Fragment`s.

Thank you in advance for your help.

### Edit

I ended up picking the solution I did because it works. The videoview and controller need to be recreated each time onCreateView is called and the playback position needs to be set in onResume and recored in onPause. However, the playback is choppy during the rotation. The solution is not optimal but it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `mVideoPlayer = (VideoView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);`
Your `VideoView` is created by the activity which is being destroyed and recreated on rotation. This means a new `R.id.videoPlayer` VideoView is being created. So your local `mVideoPlayer` is just being overwritten in your above line. Your fragment needs to create the `VideoView` in its onCreateView() method. Even then, this may not suffice. Because Views are inherently linked with their owning Context. Perhaps an explicit pause, detect and attach, play of the view would be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations:

1.First of all, you should know that even if a fragment is retained the activity gets distroyed.
As a result, the `onCreate()` method of activity, where you add the fragment, is called every time thus resulting in multple fragments overlaping each other.

In `VideoPlayerActivity` you need a mechanism to determine whether the activity is created for the first time, or is re-created due to a configuration change.
You can solve this problem by putting a flag in `onSaveInstanceState()` and then checking the `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate()`. If it's null, it means the activity is created for the first time, so only now you can add the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        createNewWorkerFragment();
    }
}

// ....

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("fragment_added", true);
}
```

2.Secondly, in `VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment` you are refering to the `VideoView` declared in the activity:

```
mVideoPlayer = (VideoView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
```

which gets destroyed when the screen is rotated.

What you should do, is to extract that `VideoView` and put it in a separate layout file that will be inflated by the fragment in the `onCreateView()` method.
But even here you may have some troubles. Despide the fact that `setRetainInstance(true)` is called, `onCreateView()` is called every time on screen orientation, thus resulting in re-inflation of your layout.

The solution would be to inflate the layout in `onCreateView()` only once:

```
public class VideoPlayerActivityWorkerFragment extends Fragment {
   private View view;

   //.....

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_video_view, container, false);
            mVideoPlayer = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
            // .....
        } else {
            // If we are returning from a configuration change:
            // "view" is still attached to the previous view hierarchy
            // so we need to remove it and re-attach it to the current one
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
        return view;
    }
   }
}
```

If all the above said does not make sense for you, reserve some time to play with fragments, especially inflation of a layout in a fragment, then come back and read this answer again.

Comment: If I am reading your second point correctly then I need to have two layout files, one with a (I guess) FrameLayout and another with the actual VideoView. The FrameLayout would get inflated by the activity and the VideoView would get inflated by the fragment and then inserted into the FrameLayout?

Comment: I have done what you described and I get an error complaining that the activity used to create the VideoView is not running. As far as I can tell there is no way to change the context of a VideoView so I will need to create a new one each time and seek to the correct spot correct?

Comment: The problem with this, is that view which is retained in the fragment is inflated with first activity as the context.  After activity is re-created, this old activity context could cause problems i.e. leaking or crashing.