# android:screenOrientation=”locked” on old OS versions

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation, android-orientation

Even if device is rotated, I want my activity to maintain the orientation it was started in, whether it was portrait or landscape. API level 18 introduced [`android:screenOrientation=”locked”`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) that should do the job: `Locks the orientation to its current rotation, whatever that is.`

However, I want to support also older OS versions. How can I achieve this?

I'm aware of [Lock screen orientation (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android) that discusses locking activity to landscape mode, [How do I disable orientation change on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android) that discusses locking activity in portrait mode (that did not work for me at all on Samsung Galaxy S, OS 2.3.3). I'm also aware of [advice recommending not to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336057/1097104).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*MainActivity.java*:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration. ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    else
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // ...
}
```

I have also modified the manifest file. However, I'm not sure if these changes are needed, at least `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"` is the default screenOrientation value anyway. *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="unspecified" />
```