# How to display the ProgressDialog when do network operations using volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am Woking on an android application where I am very interested to use `volley` library to perform the network http calls.

But my question I found that this library do operations in different background thread then How I can show`ProgressDialog` when http request start to execute then later dismiss it once it has executed.

```
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        tv.setText(response); // We set the response data in the TextView
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        System.out.println("Error ["+error+"]");

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You display one at request and dismiss it in onResponse or onErrorResponse.

Comment: @greenapps can you please give an example to me ?

Comment: What is the problem? Just create a ProgressDialog before the code you posted. Or at the moment you put postReq in the queue. And show him. Or is there an onStart event?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. Start the progress dialog once you add the request object in the queue.

```
//add the request to the queue
rq.add(request);

//initialize the progress dialog and show it
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching The File....");
progressDialog.show();
```

Then dismiss the dialog once you have received the response from the server.

```
StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        tv.setText(response); // We set the response data in the TextView
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(“Volly Error”,”Error: ”+error.getLocalizedMessage());
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: How do we handle the progress dialog if the activity is recreated during orientation changes without using configChanges in manifest?

Comment: This answer is not a complete solution. What if you change the orientation? what if you press cancel progress - where does the network operation get's cancelled?

Comment: That's a very old issue and somewhat unrelated to this question and solution. The orientation change can cause problem to any activity/view if you are not careful enough to handle that. See here for more info: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html . You can also check discussion on this issue in SO. One example is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5336057/3784165