# Recycler items get loaded after onPostExecute

Tags: java, android

I am loading data using `Volley` call within an `AsyncTask`. And also did coding to display the `ProgressDialog`. But the problem is `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` so fast that `ProgressDialog` do not appear and still the items are not visible after few seconds

Comment: *I am loading data using Volley call within an AsyncTask* ... why? volley is already an async library ...  Please learn basic flow in multithreading ... *But the problem is onPreExecute and onPostExecute so fast that ProgressDialog do not appear* ... I'm pretty sure that you are hinding it before any of this methods call ... let me guess: `new Task().execute(); dialog.dismiss();` or asynchronous call in `doInBackground`

Comment: Please provide your code?

Comment: No, I am dismissing it under onPostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the execution of your `AsyncTask` **looks** extremely fast (even faster than you getting the result for your request) is probably that by using Volley inside AsyncTask you are using volley's thread to make the network request instead of the async task thread.

This would make it look like the async task executed really fast, when  in fact **you just passed the work on to another thread** (volley's thread) so AsyncTask concludes its work and you still have nothing, then volley finishes its work and you get the result.

Solution:

Either use Android volley OR use `AsyncTask`

As you can see in the [volley training docs](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json) there is no need for `AsyncTask`

You can also see [this SO AsyncTask example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24399320/2819928) and verify that since `doInBackgound()` runs in another thread, there is no need to use volley or another async method

Update to answer the question in the comments:

How to use `ProgressDialog` with volley?

It is actually very easy as stated in [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251102/2819928) SO post for example

You just have two steps:

1. You start your `ProgressDialog` as you add your Volley request to the queue
   ;)

   //add the request to the queue
       rq.add(request);

   ```
   //initialize the progress dialog and show it
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
   progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching The File....");
   progressDialog.show();
   ```
2. You dismiss your dialog inside your OnResponse()

   ```
   StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", new Response.Listener<String>() 
   {

       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
           tv.setText(response); // We set the response data in the TextView
           progressDialog.dismiss();
       }
   }, 

   new Response.ErrorListener() {

           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Log.e(“Volly Error”,”Error: ”+error.getLocalizedMessage());
               progressDialog.dismiss();
           }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I want to use volley call I have no option. So If I am doing that then how will I show my own ProgressDialog

Comment: I was trying your suggestion and I got the run time error states that `Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: @AkshayDusane without your code it will be difficult to pinpoint the error.
But just from that it looks like you are having trouble instantiating the ProgressDialog, try substituting  ::: new ProgressDialog(getActivity);  ---->>    **new ProgressDialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this);**

Let me know if it worked

Comment: Actually I have made one separate class for all my VolleyRequest which do not extends any Fragment or Activity. And also I tried your suggestion of `new ProgressDialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this)` . It says it is not an enclosing class and the remedy to it is to make the class static. But I want to avoid this. Is it a correct way to do it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128627/discussion-between-henriquems-and-akshay-dusane).