# How to switch to full screen by turning phone to landscape mode and not affecting the streaming video

Tags: android

I am creating a video streaming application , I want when I switch to landscape it goes to full screen but it should not load the video from the start again. I want to to switch smoothly without affecting the current playing.Help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vid);
        String vidAddress = "http://campusvibe.co.nf/blender.mp4";
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        videoView.start();


    }
}
```

This is for the portrait  mode

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3090C7">


        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
</VideoView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is for the landscape mode

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3090C7">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the IMA SDK sample app sources:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-android

It does what you want.

Hope this help you

Comment: Thank You ..Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your activity in which the video is being played in the AndroidManifest.xml file

android:configChanges="orientation"
This prevents the activity from being recreated. Hope this helps!

Comment: The playing video still starts again. after inserting that.

Comment: The `configChanges` attribute can open a can of worms though, and should really only be a last resort, as everything relating to config changes must now be handled manually. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335665/avoid-reloading-activity-with-asynctask-on-orientation-change-in-android/5336057) and [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putInt("movLength", mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition());
  // value equals to where user watched the
  // etc.
}
```

and on the activity check if the Bundle savedInstanceState != null:

```
  int movlength = 0;    
  if (savedInstanceState != null){
  movlength = savedInstanceState.getInt("movLength");
  }
  mediaplayer.seekto(movlength);
  // etc
```

Copy above to the onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

By default, each time you change an orientation, the view is recreated again. to prevent this you can use the `android:configChanges="orientation` but it is preferable to save the state as at when the orientation changes.

As your activity begins to stop, the system calls `onSaveInstanceState()` so your activity can save state information with a collection of key-value pairs. The default implementation of this method saves information about the state of the activity's view hierarchy, such as the text in an EditText widget or the scroll position of a ListView.

To save additional state information for your activity such as the position of the streaming video, you must implement `onSaveInstanceState()` and add key-value pairs to the Bundle object. For example:

```
...

 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Save the current streaming position or state
       percentage = controls.getBufferPercentage()
       position =   controls.getCurrentPosition()
savedInstanceState.putInt("percentage", percentage);
savedInstanceState.putInt("position", position);

// Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

implement `onRestoreInstanceState`, this is called when re-creating.

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

// Restore state members from saved instance
mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
mCurrentPercentage = savedInstanceState.getInt("percentage");

 // then you can use the MediaControls to restore the streaming app to the current position
}
```