# Crash after a day

Tags: android

It seems like my application crashes after it is not used for a long time...
To reproduce: do not use the application for one day. Then try to start again.

I guess it happens when application is in Stop mode, but can't be sure.
My question is - how do I debug this?
Also - how can I prevent this?

And I believe this is what causes it:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:391)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:236)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Would you mind changing your window orientation and seeing if that has anything tod o with the crash?

Comment: Do you have and progress dialogs that are getting dismissed?

Comment: I do not have progress dialog on first screen. Also the first screen has:
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution: [How to handle screen orientation change when progress dialog and background thread active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-threa)

> When you switch orientations, Android will create a new View. You're probably getting crashes because your background thread is trying to change the state on the old one. (It may also be having trouble because your background thread isn't on the UI thread)

tl;dr: you have to update your screen handler when the device orientation changes.

Comment: I think he meant 'change the orientation and see if that doesn't cause the same crash'.

Comment: Precisely. Maybe the daily usage causes orientation changes, and those   cause the problem.