# Android orientation and keyboard issue

Tags: android, keyboard, orientation

I've been doing final testing on my app and everything is solid, except last night I noticed that when I flip the keyboard out on my friend's Motorola Droid, it restarts the activity or crashes (if it is doing work at the time the keyboard is open) the app.  Ive done some searhing online and in a book I have and havent found much on this topic.

My screens are all locked into portrait mode for good reason.  I need to make sure sliding out a keyboard simply allows the app to continue doing what it is doing.  I dont need to change orientation or anything, just trap the event and allow the app to keep going...

Comment: Could you post the LogCat of the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post

[How to handle screen orientation change when progress dialog and background thread active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-threa/2418763#2418763)

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest for your activity there is something called `configChanges`. If this is not set then events like this (keyboard pulling, orientation change etc.) will restart your activity.

Just look over on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) for the article on handling orientation changes. its the same principle for keyboard changes.