# Crash on orientation change

Tags: android

I have an application when I click a button then execute `AsyncTask` in that `onPreExecute` show ProgressDialog code and in `onPostExecute` i am using `dialog.dismiss()`.

In my manifest file I declare `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in `Activity`, but when I click button start `ProgressDialog` and when change screen orientation it crashes.

After searching, I got this link [How to handle screen orientation change when progress dialog and background thread active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-threa).

But, I can't understand what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Can you post your Manifest file?

Comment: have you added `android:configChanges="orientation"` in activity tag in manifest file ?

Comment: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` should work, there is likely something wrong in Manifest. You are using unmanaged dialogs. Try look at `Activity.showDialog(int)` for managed dialogs. Managed dialogs are saved when Activity is being recreated and then restored by Activity for you.

Comment: Inside `onPostExecute` you check first whether your dialog is showing or not. If yes then call `dismiss()`; `if(dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: Yes i added.
 <activity android:name=".Homemenu" android:label="Home Menu"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
   android:configChanges="orientation"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Comment: i checkd like this  if (dialog != null) { 
     dialog.dismiss();
      }

Comment: Did you check `if(dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();` inside `onPostExecute()` ? what are the results ?

Comment: that also not work. thanks for reply

Comment: Please post a comment for clarification in the original thread, then. There are many different answer (mine is to not use AsyncTask)

Answer (score 3):

You can put a line `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your manifest or
You can dismiss dialog in `onDestoy()` method of activity. for that you have to declare progressdialog globally and in `onDestoy()` check progress dialog

for example

```
if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
progressDialog  = null;
}
```

Comment: if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
//progressDialog  = null;
} this is working for me so +1 for you thanks for reply

Comment: Please mark this question as solved any of the answer worked for you

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Activity is trying to dismiss the dialog which has already lost its context.
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` add this to your Activity in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the previous answers, speaking about dismissing the dialog in `onDestoy()` and `onPostExecute`.

**1/ There is a problem :** The fact `onDestoy()` and `onPostExecute` are not always lunched ! So anyway , you can have this problem of crash ... 
->It would be better to dismiss your dialog in `onPause()` and in the end of `doInBackground()`.

The fact is that everytime that your orientation changes, a new `View` is created. Then you can make your activity handle better this by adding the `onConfigChanges` propertiy in your XML:

```
<activity ...
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

So to conclude, you define your `ProgressDialog` as global property in your activity, then you are sure that it's part of the activity Context, and you can update from everywhere in your activity ... You add a methode that dismiss the progress with checking it :

```
/**
 * Instance of ProgressDialog.
 */
private ProgressDialog dialog;
```

you can instantiate and it somewhere in your code like this :

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    // show the loading dialog
    dialog.show();
```

now the dismiss methode:

```
/**
 * check that the dialog exists before dismissing it.
 */
private void dialogDismiss() {
    try {
        if (Util.isNotEmpty(dialog)) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "problem with the dialog dismiss again !!!", e);
    }
}
```

then from everywhere in this activity, you call `dialogDismiss();` and your dialog is dismissed !

Kind regards,
good luck !