# Android handling orientationg change with model object and ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, orientation-changes, android-orientation

I have an `Android` application which retrieves information from the web using an `AsyncTask`. The main `Activity` has a model object, and the AsyncTask calls a method on this object to go and retrieve the data. While this is going on, the main Activity fires off a `ProgressDialog`. As you can imagine, this was not implemented with orientation changes in mind. I know I can save the model object instance away using the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method. But what do I do with the `ProgressDialog`? Can I save that away in the same method? Should I destroy it and recreate it? Or should I do a 3rd thing?

**Quick Edit**: While I'm on the topic, have any of the Android Engineers actually commented on the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been detailed discussions on how to do this here at SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre), for example). It definitely is not something simple and requires lot of housekeeping on the part of the developer.

Comment: I find it mind boggling that Google would have dropped the ball on something so simple like this.