# Confused about handling turning android

Tags: android

Learning android programming, I posted a question recently, which helped me move along with the issue, however I still can't quite fix the problem.

The problem is that each time I turn my android, my app pretty much dies.

Here's what happens:
I got onTouchEvent, which prints anytime a screen is touched (this is before I turn the tablet):

```
03-13 22:26:04.544: D/DEBUG(4084): onTouchEvent(MotionEvent{5a481bc0 action=1 x=314.0 y=506.0 pressure=0.0 size=0.0})
And this happens right after I turn the tablet:
03-13 22:26:07.059: D/sensors(1873): input_event iev->type:1 iev->code:101 iev->value:5 
03-13 22:26:07.059: E/WindowOrientationListener(1873): georgezhou++++++++=- onSensorChanged, rotation = 0
03-13 22:26:07.064: D/sensors(1873): hardware/libhardware/modules/sensors/sensors.cpp::data_poll 
03-13 22:26:07.089: E/WindowManager(1873): computeNewConfigurationLocked
03-13 22:26:07.089: I/ActivityManager(1873): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=md_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=19}
03-13 22:26:07.159: D/DEBUG(4084): Called onStop()
03-13 22:26:07.159: D/DEBUG(4084): Called onDestroy
```

I printed the 'onStop() message when I got it, and same for OnDestroy, my methods first call super., than print the message.

The onCreate() actually has code that creates a thread, and keeps redrawing the screen. - I currently do not pause or kill this thread.

How come there's no call to onRestart or onResume?
And I don't see onPause, which I expected from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle

This might be important, I have this setting: minSdkVersion="4"
That's because I'm using Pandigital, and that seems to be the highest I can go.

Comment: this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter...)

The solution is outlined here:

[How to handle screen orientation change when progress dialog and background thread active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre)