# YouTube video full screen mode switches activity-UI into landscape mode

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube, landscape-portrait

In my android app, I am playing a youtube video using `WebView` with `IFrame`. When the activity-UI is in portrait mode and I click on the youtube video at the bottom right corner to make it full screen, it appears to have have become full screen for a second. But then it switches back to original size quickly and the activity-UI goes into landscape mode.

Comment: if possible then set SetRequestedOrientation to Portrait when you start playing video.

Comment: @imrankhan thanks for the comment. Indeed I needed to do that. But the problem was still there. Then I found solution on another stack-overflow question. I also had to put `android:configChanges="orientation"` in AndroidManifest file for that activity.

Comment: I found the solution on another stack-overflow question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre)
I had to do this:
`android:configChanges="orientation"` in my AndroidManifest file for that activity.
The problem is when orientation changes, the activity is destroyed and setting this doesn't destroy the activity it only invokes the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on another stack-overflow question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre) I had to do this: `android:configChanges="orientation"` in my AndroidManifest file for that activity. The problem is when orientation changes, the activity is destroyed and setting this doesn't destroy the activity it only invokes the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method.