# How to play YouTube video directly in landscape mode in fullscreen?

Tags: java, android

So, I'm using this code to play some video after a button click:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYqhW2YFN7k")));
```

But it just opens the whole youtube web page in the browser with suggested videos and stuff. Is there a way to directly play the video in landscape mode in fullscreen?

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ on how to embed YouTube player in your application.

Comment: You can try some option right here ->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108441/play-youtube-video-in-full-screen-mode-in-my-android-app

Answer (score 2):

If You are using Youtubeplayer APi to view video than you can use this line in onInitializationSuccess Method

```
youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your screen orientation landscape in android manifestfile.

Comment: Yes, but my orientation is portrait where my imagebutton is, with which I start the YouTube video. And it can't be landscape, cause of the design. I guess, when I start the video the next activity is web browser.

Comment: If you set your orientation landscape in manifest file means all design should be landscape mode only.

Comment: Well, I don't wanna do that.

Comment: check this this will help "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960582/youtube-video-full-screen-mode-switches-activity-ui-into-landscape-mode"

Comment: try this also "intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); "

Comment: I don't know what I get with that "force_fullscreen" that I send with an intent? Nothing, cause I tried.

Comment: what version you are using.

Comment: intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); it work on 4.1  and higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [**YouTube Data API**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) by Google.

There, you have a lot of control of how to show the video. This includes even putting the view that shows the video into your activity, so you can set whatever orientation you wish for it.