# VideoView Layout changes not reflected when video is paused

Tags: android, orientation, android-videoview

I have a layout which has a video view as its child and another navigation bar that appears on touch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/main_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mediaplayer_navigation_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_header"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mediaplayer_navigation_back"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            style="@style/text_shadow"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@color/navigation_bar_text_color"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/back_arrow_button_click"
            android:onClick="mediaplayerBackButtonClickHandler" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mediaplayer_navigation_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/tranceparent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            style="@style/text_shadow"
            android:textColor="@color/navigation_bar_text_color"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/my_video"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem i face is that when the device is in the portrait mode and the navigation bar is visible, and i pause the video and switch to landscape and touch to make the navigation bar disappear, the black bar is on the video where the bar was.
i tried invalidating, setting the layout parameters but nothing seems to be making any change
can this be a device specific issue? im currently testing with HTC Sensation

**UPDATE**

This issue is not reproducible in Samsung S2 but other view issues in the similar scenarios in Asus tab :(

Comment: what is parent of the RelativeLayout ?

Comment: another Relative layout, i have updated the xml field

Comment: do i have your main_background style code ?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer it does nothin much other than setting the height and width and a background color.

Comment: can you please remove that line and try once. And let me know

Comment: @iDroidExplorer no change.. :(

Comment: hummm. Ok try to taking Your navigationbar as LinearLayout and thn try it.

Comment: @Preethi dont give any orientation to `RelativeLayout` its meaningless.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer are u sure these changes are goin to bring any change? the video is not getting updated when its in the Paused state right.. any idea how to do it?

Comment: @Preethi you can see this question to handle your screen mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre