# ProgressBar crash after orientation change

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-orientation

I am having a problem with a task that shows live content from a site.

I have been playing around with this code for a while and playing around with the status but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

The only solution I have been able to come up with so far is completely disable orientation changes, but I would prefer not to do that if possible.

Here is the Stack Trace:

> STACK_TRACE = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
>     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:653)
>     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:349)
>     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:160)
>     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:319)
>     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:302)
>     at cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion.Progress.dismiss(Progress.java:72)
>     at cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion.AdditionalMaterial.databaseLoaded(AdditionalMaterial.java:149)
>     at cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion.AdditionalMaterial.access$13(AdditionalMaterial.java:122)
>     at cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion.AdditionalMaterial$1$1.run(AdditionalMaterial.java:73)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is my code for the class that is crashing:

```
package cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion.DBSchema.DBAdditionalMaterial;
import cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion.DBSchema.DBAdditionalMaterialGroups;
import cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion.Files.Download;

public class AdditionalMaterial extends ActionBarActivity implements ListenerXML, ListenerDownload, ListenerAsync {
    private final static String URL = "action=downloads";

    private XMLParser xmlParser;
    private Progress progress = null;

    // Parsers
    private SQLParser sqlParser;

    private Handler threadHandler = new Handler();

    // The database
    private SQLiteDatabase tronDB;

    private int downloadId = 0;
    private boolean downloadAll = false;
    private int downloadCount = 1;

    private int firstDownloadAvailable = 0;

    private String fileName;

    private Files files = new Files();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("debug", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_additional_material);

        //progress = new Progress();
        //progress.show(this, this, false);

        sqlParser = new SQLParser(this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tronDB = sqlParser.getWritableDatabase();   
                threadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        databaseLoaded();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("debug", "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d("debug", "onRestart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        progress = new Progress();
        progress.show(this, this, false);

        Log.d("debug", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("debug", "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        progress = null;

        Log.d("debug", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d("debug", "onDestroy");
    }

    private void databaseLoaded() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        long materialDate = settings.getLong(Settings.MATERIAL_DATE, Settings.MATERIAL_DATE_DEFAULT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long currentDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        if (currentDate > materialDate ) {
            // Update the database
            String rut = settings.getString(Settings.RUT, Settings.RUT_DEFAULT);
            String password = settings.getString(Settings.PASSWORD, Settings.PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postData.put("rut", rut);
            postData.put("pass", password);

            xmlParser = new XMLParser(this, postData);
            xmlParser.fetchListener = this; // Tell the XMLParser that this activity has the listener
            xmlParser.execute(MainActivity.URL + URL);
        }
        else {
            // Material does not need to be updated, just show what is in the database
            if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) { 
                progress.dismiss();
            }
            ShowContent showContent = new ShowContent(this);
            showContent.asyncListener = this; // Tell the task that this class is listening
            showContent.execute();
        }
    }

    private void fetchFinished(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> xmlData) {
        // Let's put the groups in the database
        HashMap<String, String> xmlHash = xmlData.get("1");
        String groups = xmlHash.get("groups");
        for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.valueOf(groups); i++) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.COLUMN_ID, String.valueOf(i));
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.COLUMN_NAME, xmlHash.get("group" + String.valueOf(i)));
            tronDB.replace(
                DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                values);
        }

        // Now the material
        for (int i = 2; i <= xmlData.size() - 1; i++) {
            xmlHash = xmlData.get(String.valueOf(i));

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID, xmlHash.get("id"));
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_NAME, xmlHash.get("title"));
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_GROUP, xmlHash.get("group"));
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_TYPE, xmlHash.get("type"));
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_URL1, xmlHash.get("url1"));
            values.put(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_URL2, xmlHash.get("url2"));
            tronDB.replace(
                DBAdditionalMaterial.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                values);
        }

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor settingsEditor = settings.edit();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long currentDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        settingsEditor.putLong(Settings.MATERIAL_DATE, currentDate);
        settingsEditor.commit();

        progress.dismiss();

        ShowContent showContent = new ShowContent(this);
        showContent.asyncListener = this; // Tell the task that this class is listening
        showContent.execute();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
    protected class ShowContent extends AsyncTask<String, View, Void> {
        private Context context;
        private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
        protected ListenerAsync asyncListener = null; // This needs to be set from the parent activity

        private LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        protected ShowContent(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Let's make sure the CPU doesn't go to sleep
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... passedInfo) {   
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View categoryView;
            View downloadView;
            View seperatorView;
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context);

            Cursor cursorMaterialGroups = tronDB.query(
                DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.TABLE_NAME,
                DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.ALL_COLUMNS,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.COLUMN_ID + " ASC",
                null);

            while (cursorMaterialGroups.moveToNext()) {
                // Create a group TextView by inflating a layout
                categoryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.additional_material_category, null);
                textView = (TextView) categoryView;
                textView.setText(cursorMaterialGroups.getString(cursorMaterialGroups.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.COLUMN_NAME)));

                publishProgress(textView);

                // Now to get the downloads from the group
                Cursor cursorMaterial = tronDB.query(DBAdditionalMaterial.TABLE_NAME,
                    DBAdditionalMaterial.ALL_COLUMNS,
                    DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_GROUP + "=" + cursorMaterialGroups.getString(cursorMaterialGroups.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterialGroups.COLUMN_ID)),
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID + " ASC",
                    null);

                downloadCount += cursorMaterial.getCount();

                while (cursorMaterial.moveToNext()) {
                    downloadView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.additional_material_download, null);
                    // Download title
                    textView = (TextView) downloadView.findViewById(R.id.download_title);
                    textView.setText(cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_NAME)));

                    // Download/play button
                    imageButton = (ImageButton) downloadView.findViewById(R.id.download_button);
                    imageButton.setId(Integer.valueOf(cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID))));
                    String fileName = null;
                    if (cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_TYPE)).equals("pdf")) {
                        fileName = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID)) + ".pdf";
                    }
                    else {
                        fileName = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID)) + ".mp3";
                    }
                    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                    if (!files.fileExists(context, fileName)) {
                        if (firstDownloadAvailable == 0) {
                            firstDownloadAvailable = imageButton.getId();
                        }
                        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_save);
                        imageButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                downloadId = view.getId();
                                download();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        imageButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                String contentId = String.valueOf(view.getId());
                                openContent(contentId);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    publishProgress(downloadView);

                    if (!cursorMaterial.isLast()) {
                        seperatorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.additional_material_seperator, null);
                        publishProgress(seperatorView);
                    }
                }

                cursorMaterial.close();
            }

            // Other
            categoryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.additional_material_category, null);
            textView = (TextView) categoryView;
            textView.setText("OTHER");

            publishProgress(textView);

            // Download all

            downloadView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.additional_material_download, null);
            // Download title
            textView = (TextView) downloadView.findViewById(R.id.download_title);
            textView.setText("Download all material");

            // Download/play button
            imageButton = (ImageButton) downloadView.findViewById(R.id.download_button);
            imageButton.setId(1);
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_save);
            imageButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    downloadId = firstDownloadAvailable;
                    downloadAll = true;
                    download();
                }
            });

            publishProgress(downloadView);

            cursorMaterialGroups.close();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(View... view) {
            linearLayout.addView(view[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            wakeLock.release();
            if (asyncListener != null) {
                // Call the listener if one is set
                asyncListener.onAsyncComplete();
            }
        }
    }

    private void download() {
        progress.show(this, this, true);
        Files files = new Files();
        // Check if the memory card can be written to
        if (files.isWriteable()) {

            Cursor cursorMaterial = tronDB.query(DBAdditionalMaterial.TABLE_NAME,
                DBAdditionalMaterial.ALL_COLUMNS,
                DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(downloadId),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                "1");

            cursorMaterial.moveToFirst();
            String title = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_NAME));
            String type = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_TYPE));
            String url1 = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_URL1));
            String url2 = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_URL2));
            cursorMaterial.close();

            if (type.equals("pdf")) {
                fileName = String.valueOf(downloadId) + ".pdf";
            }
            else {
                fileName = String.valueOf(downloadId) + ".mp3";
            }

            // Change the message in the downloading prompt
            progress.setMessage(getString(R.string.general_downloading) + " " + title);

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String rut = settings.getString(Settings.RUT, Settings.RUT_DEFAULT);
            String url = url1 + rut + url2;
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");

            final Download download = files.new Download(this, fileName, progress);
            download.downloadListener = this;
            download.execute(url);

            progress.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    downloadAll = false;
                    download.cancel(true);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.general_no_memory), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void openContent(String contentId) {        
        Cursor cursorMaterial = tronDB.query(DBAdditionalMaterial.TABLE_NAME,
            DBAdditionalMaterial.ALL_COLUMNS,
            DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID + "=" + contentId,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            "1");

        cursorMaterial.moveToFirst();
        String type = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_TYPE));
        cursorMaterial.close();

        String fileName = "";
        String mimeType = "";

        if (type.equals("pdf")) {
            fileName = contentId + ".pdf";
            mimeType = "application/pdf";
        }
        else {
            fileName = contentId + ".mp3";
            mimeType = "audio/mp3";
        }

        files.openFile(this, fileName, mimeType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectionFailed.RETRY, false)) {
            // Failed, let's try the connection again
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String rut = settings.getString(Settings.RUT, Settings.RUT_DEFAULT);
            String password = settings.getString(Settings.PASSWORD, Settings.PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postData.put("rut", rut);
            postData.put("pass", password);

            xmlParser = new XMLParser(this, postData);
            xmlParser.fetchListener = this; // Tell the XMLParser that this activity has the listener
            xmlParser.execute(MainActivity.URL + URL);
        }
    }

    // This is the listener for the xml
    public void onFetchComplete(String xml) {
        if (xml == null) {
            progress.dismiss();
            // Failed to fetch xml, either a server error or an internet connection problem
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionFailed.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> xmlHash = xmlParser.parseXML(xml);
            new User().checkUserValidation(xmlHash.get("0"));
            fetchFinished(xmlHash);
        }
    }

    // This is the listener for the download
    public void onDownloadComplete(boolean result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        if (!result) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.general_failed_download), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.general_download_complete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            ImageButton buttonView = (ImageButton) findViewById(downloadId);
            buttonView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String contentId = String.valueOf(view.getId());
                    openContent(contentId);
                }
            });
            if (downloadAll) {
                while (downloadCount >= downloadId) {
                    downloadId++;
                    Cursor cursorMaterial = tronDB.query(DBAdditionalMaterial.TABLE_NAME,
                        DBAdditionalMaterial.ALL_COLUMNS,
                        DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(downloadId),
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        "1");

                    cursorMaterial.moveToFirst();
                    String type = cursorMaterial.getString(cursorMaterial.getColumnIndex(DBAdditionalMaterial.COLUMN_TYPE));
                    cursorMaterial.close();

                    if (type.equals("pdf")) {
                        fileName = String.valueOf(downloadId) + ".pdf";
                    }
                    else {
                        fileName = String.valueOf(downloadId) + ".mp3";
                    }

                    if (!files.fileExists(this, fileName)) {
                        download();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (downloadCount == downloadId) {
                    // The last one downloaded we can now stop the process
                    downloadAll = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This is the listener for the Async
    public void onAsyncComplete() {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my progress bar:

```
package cl.cromer.tronwell.concepcion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

public final class Progress {

    protected ProgressDialog progressBar = null;
    private int oldOrientation = -1; // Orientation not set
    private Activity activity;

    protected void show(Context context, Activity activity, boolean cancelable) {
        this.activity = activity;

        // Disable rotation while we are loading something
        oldOrientation = activity.getRequestedOrientation();
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

        if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(oldOrientation);
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }

        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressBar.setCancelable(cancelable);

        if (!cancelable) {
            progressBar.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.general_loading));
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        }
        else {
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressBar.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.general_downloading));
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        }
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();
    }

    protected void setMessage(String message) {
        progressBar.setMessage(message);
    }

    protected void setIndeterminate(boolean indeterminate) {
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    }

    protected void setProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }

    protected void setOnCancelListener(DialogInterface.OnCancelListener listener) {
        progressBar.setOnCancelListener(listener);
    }

    protected boolean isShowing() {
        if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void dismiss() {
        // Turn rotation back to it's previous state
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(oldOrientation);
        if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: go through this and make appropriate changes:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check answer of this question [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre)

I think you facing same issue

Check this one as well [Answer 2](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/)

Comment: Thanks, Answer 2 has everything I was looking for.