# Stop Dialog from showing after orientation changes

Tags: android, dialog, orientation, dismiss, orientation-changes

I have a custom Dialog class in which I instantiate the dialog like this

```
dg = new Dialog(con); 
dg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
Window window = dg.getWindow();
window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
dg.setContentView(R.layout.listview_dialog_layout); 

//set views etc..

dg.show();
```

When an orientation change occurs in the activity that the dialog is shown the activity data changes are lost but the dialog still stays open. I would like the dialog to be dismissed at orientation changes just like it happens with the default Dialog created through an AlertDialog.Builder. How can I do that?

I prefer a solution that is implemented in the custom Dialog class instead of going to every activity and type dialog.dismiss(); at activity pause or stop

Comment: Detect the orientation change and close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33787318/3992997)

This method lets you detect orientation changes for a dialog without a reference to an Activity.  It requires a custom view within the dialog, though. If you can pass an instance of your custom dialog class to the custom view, you can call `dialog.dismiss();` directly within the onConfigurationChanged() method of the custom view.