# Screen orientation issue on Nougat 7.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have two activities in my application both supports portrait and landscape orientation.

1. Initially application loaded perfect
2. Rotate my screen to landscape and then come back to portrait, now my portrait views are not showing good as I designed

the layout `android:weightSum` is not working fine most of the layout weight are reduced

**manifest.xml**

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: _now my portrait views are now showing good as I designed_ if it is the same then what is the issue?

Comment: sorry man updated the question please check now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle screen orientation change when progress dialog and background thread active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre)

Comment: thanks for your response, my question is entirely different

Comment: my question something like below scenario https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69168442