# How to return a variable from AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I have an implementation of a `Fragment` class.The class is supposed to return a `view` of a graph plotted dynamically using data from a remote server.Everything is working ok.But now i want to implement an `AsyncTask` class to increase responsiveness of the app.Problem is how do i return an `ArrayList` to the calling class.I can't seem to locate a good example from the internet.
Here is my method which creates and returns the view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfragment, container, false);
    sharename = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_SHARENAME);
    // performance = getPerformance(sharename);
    // new GraphSharePerformance().execute();

    new GraphSharePerformance() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SharePerformance> param) {
            super.onPostExecute(param);
            ArrayList<SharePerformance> results = param;
            performance = param;
            // USE THE RESULT here
        }
    }.execute();

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    layout.addView(displayLineChart(performance));
    return v;
}
```

And this is my `AsyncTask` class:

```
protected class GraphSharePerformance extends
            AsyncTask<GraphFragment, Void, ArrayList<SharePerformance>> {
        ArrayList<SharePerformance> shareperformance = new ArrayList<SharePerformance>();

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<SharePerformance> doInBackground(
                GraphFragment... params) {
            shareperformance = getPerformance(sharename);
            return shareperformance;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SharePerformance> param) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

Now how do i get the returned `ArrayList`?I have tried using a global variable to hold the `arraylist` but this doesn't work even though it has always worked in other classes.The graph does not plot any value.I will appreciate help on this.Thank you.

Comment: use interface http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask

Comment: Can you not just put the logic you want to apply on the list inside onPostExecute?

Comment: Use [Listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447646/how-do-i-send-data-back-from-onpostexecute-in-an-asynctask), and try [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=listener+in+onpostexecute&oq=listener+in+onpostexecute&aqs=chrome..69i57.8394j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) too

Comment: I usually implements the delegate pattern

Comment: @cYrixmorten no i cant do that because if i do i cannot.It is not possible and viable for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is **ONE** way:

```
protected class GraphSharePerformance extends
        AsyncTask<GraphFragment, Void, ArrayList<SharePerformance>> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<SharePerformance> doInBackground(GraphFragment... params) {
        return getPerformance(sharename);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SharePerformance> param) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Finally, when you use your AsyncTask:

```
new GraphSharePerformance() {
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SharePerformance> param) {
      super.onPostExecute(param);
      ArrayList<SharePerformance> results = param;
      //USE THE RESULT here
   }
}.execute();
```

Comment: i have tried your implementation but i have the same problem,the graph is not plotted.I think problem is asigning the returned ArrayList to a global variable named performance.Look at my edit.

Comment: Add this line `layout.addView(displayLineChart(results));` in the place of `//USE THE RESULT here`. This means that `layout` should be a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected class GraphSharePerformance extends
    AsyncTask<GraphFragment, Void, GraphFragment> {
ArrayList<SharePerformance> shareperformance = new ArrayList<SharePerformance>();

protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected GraphFragment doInBackground(GraphFragment... params) {
    shareperformance = getPerformance(sharename);
    //return your object here. like below.
    //create object
    GraphFragment f=new GraphFragment();
    //some processing...
    //return object 
    return f;
}

protected void onPostExecute(GraphFragment param) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Application class to store values all over your app. Then you can retrieve it everywhere.

Example:

You have to declare this class as follows:

**Manifest:**

```
    <application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/graph"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Mytheme" >
```

.....

```
 </application>
```

**MyApplication class:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

private ArrayList<SharePerformance> arrayList;

public void setArrayPerf(ArrayList<SharePerformance> ap){
arrayList = ap;
}

public ArrayList<SharePerformance> getArrayPerf(){

 return arrayList;
}
}
```

**In your Activity class:**

```
 MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();

 app.setArrayPref(sharePerformance);

 ArrayList<SharePerformance> arrayList = app.getArrayPerf();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define return type as :

```
public class GraphSharePerformance extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<yourObject>>
```

And you can return that ArrayList in `doInBackground`.

At the receiving side, you need to write :

```
 ArrayList<yourObject> result = new GraphSharePerformance(args.....).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**
* How to return the ArrayList from a calling class.
**

public class AsyncTaskReturnArrayListActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {

/** Button. */
private Button button;

/** listArrayList. */
private ArrayList<String> listArrayList;

/**
 * On Create.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_task_return_array_list);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

/**
 * On Button On Click, call AsyncTask.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    /**
     * Call Async Task. Pass Calling Class Reference to Async Task. so that
     * once AsyncTask is complete it return result to calling class.
     */

    new SampleAsyncTask(this).execute();
}

/**
 * Async Task.
 */
public class SampleAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    private final AsyncTaskReturnArrayListActivity reference;

    /**
     * Constructor. Get the reference of Calling Class.
     *
     * @param reference
     */
    public SampleAsyncTask(AsyncTaskReturnArrayListActivity reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    /**
     * Pre Execute.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Pre Execute");
    }

    /**
     * Do In Background
     */
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<String> listArrayList = reference.getArrayList();
        return listArrayList;
    }

    /**
     * On Post Execute.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // On Complete send result to Calling Class.
        reference.onComplete(result);
    }
}

/**
 * Get Array List.
 *
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    ArrayList<String> listArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    listArrayList.add("String 1");
    listArrayList.add("String 2");
    listArrayList.add("String 3");
    return listArrayList;
}

/**
 * On Complete. Get's Result From Async Task.
 *
 * @param listArrayList
 */
private void onComplete(ArrayList<String> listArrayList) {
    this.listArrayList = listArrayList;
    System.out.println(this.listArrayList);
}}
```