# How to change textView properties from background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I want change the text of a textView to match the title of a website.

For this, I'm connecting to https://www.google.com and getting its html source code. Then I fetch the title tag from it. (using JSoup)

The problem is that now I don't know how to change the textView. Since the networking is happening in a background thread, I don't have access to it. How and where should I do it?

Also, I know it connected successfully thanks to Log.w.

Here's what I have:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnConnect;

    final String URL = "https://www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // launch networking task
                new EstablishConnectionTask().execute(URL);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.awakened.tirafesi.awakenedprototype.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Establish Connection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnConnect" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EstablishConnectionTask

```
public class EstablishConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String title;

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
            title = doc.title();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            title = "NO";
        }

        return title;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.w("Title", s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a listener and send it to your **EstablishConnectionTask**  then in onPostExecute just call your interface method. In your MainActivity first implement that listener and in it's override method you can set the textView's title.

Comment: To build on what @eminuluyol said, this question gives a code example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447646/how-do-i-send-data-back-from-onpostexecute-in-an-asynctask

Comment: I dont get it... How would the override of the interface method on MainActivity affect the call on the interface in onPostExecute? Would you mind adding the code for it please?

Comment: @Tirafesi check out the answer I posted man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `TextView` inside `onCreate()` same as you did for `Button`. Pass the `textView`, to `Asynctask` using the Class `Constructor`:

Complete Solved Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnConnect;
TextView textView;

final String URL = "https://www.google.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //pass TextView of this class to Asynctask cass
            new EstablishConnectionTask(textView).execute(URL);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Asynctask Class:

```
public class EstablishConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public TextView textView;

//constructor to pass textView
public EstablishConnectionTask(TextView textView){
    this.textView = textView;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String title;
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
        title = doc.title();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        title = "NO";
    }
    return title;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    textView.setText(s); // add title to textView

    Log.w("Title", s);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question shows you how to solve your issue: [how do i send data back from onPostExecute in an AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447646/how-do-i-send-data-back-from-onpostexecute-in-an-asynctask).

Change the TextView in the doStuff() interface method on the calling activity.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want know, how to access or change the UI components from the doInBackground() method or a background thread, provided AsyncTask or . To achieve this you use a handler. For example in the AsyncTask Class initialize an object of Handler
now call method handler.post() in doInBackground() method or in Run() method of thread like below

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable{
 @overide
 public void run(){
  textView.setText("Changed");
 }
});
```

remember to initialize the handler outside the doInBackground() or run() method;