# How do you run an async task then use a returned variable on the main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a ListView and a custom adapter that i wish to use to fill it with a String and an Image in an async task.  I have to get the images from a URL and the String from a text file.  This is all possible however, what i have not worked out is how to then assign the adapter to the list view as this must be done from the main thread.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do that in `onPostExecute` method. That is always called in main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what i have not worked out is how to then assign the adapter to the list view as this must be done from the main thread.

Do that work [in `onPostExecute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) of your `AsyncTask`.

> How do you run an async task then use a returned variable on the main thread?

There is no "returned value" from an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: by a returned value i mean a public variable that is defined from the task.

Comment: @Dan13_: That does not really change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), start new one inside your adapters `getView` (or similar) method. inside `doInBackground` you probably know what to do, then just return to [`onPostExecute`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) result, e.g. `Bitmap` (look out, generic!)

Answer (score 1):

Parse an interface to your adapter into your async task and call the interface from the `onPostExecute()`. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to advise when we have not seen a single line of the code you are working on. In any case, for what you asked, you have to do that in `onPostExecute` of your AsynTask. You add something like this:

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(SomeResultType results)
  {
    //your code to do stuff on UI thread goes here...
  }
```

Have a look at [the discussions and selected answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356193/instance-variable-of-activity-not-being-set-in-onpostexecute-of-asynctask-or-how?rq=1)
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the variables returned in doInBackground in the Main thread. Use the variable in the onPostExecute method to do your task.