# How to make callbacks using AsyncTask android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am making request to web service and have to do this extending **AsyncTask** for every methods. So how many methods i have in webservice that many classes i need to create in this way.

I found this topic how to make callback:
[Making Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291490/common-class-for-asynctask-in-android)

But there are shown one class callback, but what if i want that there would lots of callbacks in one class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AsyncTask` class has generic parameters for data that is passed between its methods. You can use a custom class to pass the data from one method to other.

Web-service access is usually done in 3 steps :

1. Retrieving the content (XML/JSON etc.)
2. Parsing the content
3. Reading the content.

You can pass the AsyncTask the URL to be fetched (As shown [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html))
In background you can retrieve content and parse it. The reading of content can be done in different code blocks which run on UI thread depending on the result parameter.