# How to modify external field from onPostExecute method of an inner AsyncTask class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In the following snippet:

```
public class ExternalClass {
    private int num = 1;

    public void backgroundTask() {
        new HttpTask().execute();
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    private class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Do stuff...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Do stuff...
            ExternalClass.this.num = 2;
    }
}
```

In an Activity:

```
...
ExternalClass ec = new ExternalClass();
ec.backgroundTask();
int myNum = ec.getNum(); //NUM IS 1, NOT 2!!
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything works fine, my doInBackground() and onPostExecute() complete successfully but the field "num" don't change. I tried "num = 2" or even "this.num = 2" (I know is no correct, but...).

Comment: `onPostExecute` will get fired after `doInBackground` so, calling `ec.getNum()` will never show you `myNum` as 2. Put log in `onPostExecute` and check about the value and you will see that it is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method to get result back in Main UI Thread from AsyncTask when  `doInBackground()` execution complete

```
public void backgroundTask() {
        new HttpTask().execute().get();
    }
```

**NOTE:** when u call get() method of AsyncTask in Main UI thread this will stop  exection of Main Thread . you will need to call `backgroundTask()` method from  background  Thread

Comment: Thank you! (And thank @Android-Developer too). I think I understand how it works, now. Finally, I'm going to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3291713/1369770