# How to cancel asynctask from multiple fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have app with multiple fragment.I running asynctask from fragment A and want stop it from fragment B How can I resolve this problem ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291490/common-class-for-asynctask-in-android

Comment: you can save the values from activity one and send to to second activity

Comment: I try many way but not luck

Comment: a good post on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use either use AsyncTask or AsyncTaskLoader for that. The easiest solution would probably be to do your download work in an IntentService, and communicate with it from the different activities.

Comment: My usage a a bit different, but here's my service: https://github.com/urandom/gearshift/blob/master/gearshift/src/main/java/org/sugr/gearshift/service/DataService.java#L84  and here's how i tell it what to do: https://github.com/urandom/gearshift/blob/master/gearshift/src/main/java/org/sugr/gearshift/service/DataServiceManager.java#L164  The broadcast receiver at the end of that file receives messages from the service In your case, the messages could be a list of progresses

Comment: IntentService is a better approach

Comment: But how IntentService  send data back to activity to update listview item from activity A & activity B

Comment: The services sends intents to anyone who wants to listen via: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(INTENT); any activity can then receive these events using a broadcast receiver: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(RECEIVER); when you receive such an intent in activity A or B, you update your UI accordingly

Comment: I have try your solution but it still not resolve my problem