# How to make a generic AsyncTask?

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, refactoring, httprequest

I am new to Android and I am currently working on a project that requires a lot of Http requests on a web API.

I have been searching for good practices about refactoring AsyncTask subclasses, so I don't have to write a lot of similar code into each Activity class.

Do you have any tips/advices or even an example of how you proceed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291490/common-class-for-asynctask-in-android) In this answer it has a same topic's discussion, Although i also know some blogs that can help you to make it more conceptually clear read them,

Links:

https://trinitytuts.com/reusable-asynctasks-class-in-android/

http://cyriltata.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-re-using-asynctask-class-across.html

Comment: Thanks, I have been struggling a bit with the fundamentals and the mechanics of AsyncTask but now I am able to understand the solutions you gave me.

Comment: yup, Go ahead @ozonePowered