# How to implement a listener

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listener

I have a design issue. I need to implement a listener. I saw the following SO question:
[How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android)

But in the link it provides in the answer, author creates a listener which just extends the system-defined listener. E.g onClick, you would do some validation & then call another method called "whenValidatedListener"

I need to define listeners which are not linked to existing event listeners. Basically there would be some processing going on in native(C/C++) code & in the Android code I need a listener to respond to certain messages from it.

I think I could do this using handlers. But AsyncTask is the recommended approach for multithreading.

Is there a way to implement a user-defined-listener using AsyncTask?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

AsyncTask has nothing to do with implementing a listener.

Here's a listener:

```
public interface TheListener {
    public void somethingHappened();
}
```

Call it however you want.  For example, here's a class doing something like View:

```
public class Something {
    private TheListener mTheListener;

    public void setTheListener(TheListener listen) {
        mTheListener = listen;
    }

    private void reportSomethingChanged() {
        if (mTheListener != null) {
            mTheListener.somethingHappened();
        }
    }
}
```

You can make this as complicated as you want.  For example, instead of a single listener pointer you could have an ArrayList to allow multiple listeners to be registered.

Calling this from native code also has nothing to do with implementing a listener interface.  You just need to learn about JNI to learn how native code can interact with Java language code.

Comment: Hi, I'm a little confused as to what you set the listener to in setTheListner()

Comment: The class you want to be told about something happening implements the TheListener interface.  You pass in the object implementing that interface to setTheListener().

Comment: @hackbod Should I call `new Something().setTheListener(this)` in the Class which implements **TheListener**?

Comment: wow im confused...where does the definition for somethingHappened() go??

Answer (score 5):

Just to clear things up;

you do exactly what @hackbod said and add this :

the `activity` which encloses the class (with the method `setListener(Listener listen)`), implements `Listener` and in it's `oncreate` or `onResume` or where-ever you call `yourClass.setListener(this)`.