# android how to make listener to a custom variable?

Tags: android, listener

i've seen this thread : [How to implement a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941960/android-how-to-implement-listener) about implement listeners.

its actually pretty simple but i don't get how exactly its done and how to implement in my own code.

i have this static variable variable: AppLoader.isInternetOn.
i want to build a listener which will listen to this variable changes and update a TextView.

should i do this: ?

build an interface:

```
public interface InternetStateListener {
     public void onStateChange();
}
```

run it in my activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private InternetStateListener mListener;

setTheListener(this);

public void setTheListener(InternetStateListener listen) {
    mListener = listen;
}

private void onStateChange() {
    if (mListener != null) {
       if (AppLoader.isInternetOn)
        text.setText("on")
       else
        text.setText("off")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your Activity does nothing special, just register itself (since the interface is implemented directly in the class) with the Other class that provides the listener.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements InternetManager.Listener {

    private TextView mText;
    private InternetManager mInetMgr;

    /* called just like onCreate at some point in time */ 
    public void onStateChange(boolean state) {
        if (state) {
            mText.setText("on");
        } else {
            mText.setText("off");
        }
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        mInetMgr = new InternetManager();
        mInetMgr.registerListener(this);
        mInetMgr.doYourWork();
    }
}
```

---

The other class has to do pretty much all the work. Besides that it has to handle the registration of listeners it has to call the `onStateChange` method once something happend.

```
public class InternetManager {
    // all the listener stuff below
    public interface Listener {
        public void onStateChange(boolean state);
    }

    private Listener mListener = null;
    public void registerListener (Listener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    // -----------------------------
    // the part that this class does

    private boolean isInternetOn = false;
    public void doYourWork() {
        // do things here
        // at some point
        isInternetOn = true;
        // now notify if someone is interested.
        if (mListener != null)
            mListener.onStateChange(isInternetOn);
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhhh i think iv'e now realized the architecture! many thanks!

Comment: So for any classes inheriting the interface, they will be notified with `onStateChange()` when `mListener.onStateChange(boolean)` is called directly from the interface? So its like the interface is communicating with any sub inheriting classes whenever a variable changes in the main interface after completing a task that changes the variable, right? Thanks :)

Comment: If so, how do I call `doYourWork()` from an activity?

Answer (score 0):

The part that you're missing it the class that actually notifies the listener.  So you would need a class (most likely a service) that runs and pings the state of the network.  Then when it detects a change it should call onStateChange() in any registered listeners.  Then you would call setTheListener on that service, not on your activity.

Here's a link that thoroughly describes this design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern