# How to add dynamic data (something like array of strings) to spinner

Tags: android

I have a spinner in which I am currently showing static data, how can i show dynamic data (for ex : from string array) or something like to adapter so that when i receive dynamic value from server, i can directly feed that to spinner

Below is my code :

```
if(value.contains("Extra")){
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    triangleimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(Adapter.this);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                            if (position == getCount()) {
                                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount())); //"Hint to be displayed"
                            }

                            return v;
                        }       

                        @Override
                        public int getCount() {
                            return super.getCount()-1;            // you don't display last item. It is used as hint.
                        }

                    };

                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_list);
                    adapter.add("One");
                    adapter.add("Two");
                    adapter.add("Three");
                    adapter.add("Four");
                    adapter.add("Five");
                    adapter.add("Six");
                    adapter.add("");                              //Add empty string in db option at last


                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount());     //set the hint the default selection so it appears on launch.
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();                       

                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a constructor in **ArrayAdapter** to pass array list as parameter. See the sample below.

```
    // Assume this list is from server 
     List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
     your_array_list.add("Test");
     your_array_list.add("Working");

     // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a  
     // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your  
     // array as a third parameter. 
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             your_array_list );

     yourSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks @Vino. That helped. Can you tell me how can i set "emptyvalue" as default value in same spinner, i use to do that earlier in code i posted in question, but with this even if i set first value as " ", it won't set default value in spinner as empty.

Answer (score 0):

### For Dynamic Data To Spinner

First Store All data in a arraylist or array  and then pass that to adapter of spinner it's work ...

### You can data to array

```
array_name.add(your_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener for dynamic data binding to your spinner.
[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android). [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941960/how-to-implement-a-listener)

You can use **AsyncTask** for retrieving data from server(or use your suitable method).