# Displaying text in an android studio project

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Trying to get a program similar to this to work on the android platform. The trouble is I'm not sure on using xml to display text/read user input. I'm fairly new to mobile software development but from the code below, I'm only trying to display the print statements and obviously get user input too.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class assignmentMSD
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //objects(system)
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random rand = new Random();

        //Variables used

        String[] enemies = {"Zombie", "Necromorph", "Soldier", "MadMax"};
        int maxEnemyHealth = 75;
        int enemyAttackDamage = 25;

        //Player Variables
        int health = 100;
        int attackDamage = 50;
        int numHealthElixers = 3;
        int healthPotionHeal = 30;
        int healthPotionDropChance = 50;

        boolean running = true;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Thunderdome");

        GAME:
        while(running)
        {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");

            int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
            String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
            System.out.println(" \t####" + enemy + " has appeared#### \n");

            while(enemyHealth > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\t Your Health:" + health);
                System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s Health:" + enemyHealth);
                System.out.println("\n \t What would you like to do?");
                System.out.println("\t 1. Attack");
                System.out.println("\t 2. Drink Health Potion");
                System.out.println("\t 3. Run");

                String input = in.nextLine();
                                if(input.equals("1"))
                                {
                                   int damageGiven = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
                                   int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);

                                   enemyHealth -= damageGiven;
                                   health -= damageTaken;

                                   System.out.println("\t You strike the " + enemy + " for " + damageGiven + " damage.");
                                   System.out.println("\t You take " + damageTaken + " in combat:");

                                   if(health < 1)
                                   {
                                       System.out.println("\t You have taken too much damage and therefore are too weak to fight!");
                                       break;

                                   }


                                }
                                else if(input.equals("2"))
                                {
                                   if(numHealthElixers > 0)
                                   {
                                       health += healthPotionHeal;
                                       numHealthElixers--;
                                       System.out.println("You drink a heakth potion for " + healthPotionHeal + "."
                                                            + "\n\t You now have" + health + " HP."
                                                            +"\n\t You have " + numHealthElixers + " Health Elixers left. \n");

                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                       System.out.println("\t You have no health Elixer left!, You must defeat enemies for a chance to get more \n");

                                   }
                                }
                                else if(input.equals("3"))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("\t You run away from the " + enemy + "!" );
                                    continue GAME;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("\t\n Invalid Command");
                                }
            }

                        if(health < 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You Flee from the Thunderdome, weak from battle");
                            break;
                        }

                        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(" # " + enemy + "was defeated! # ");
                        System.out.println(" # You have" + health + " HP left. #");
                        if(rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance)
                        {
                            numHealthElixers++;
                            System.out.println(" # The " + enemy + " dropped a health potion #");
                            System.out.println(" # You now have " + numHealthElixers + " Health Elixer(s). #");

                        }
                        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
                        System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
                        System.out.println("1. Continue Fighting");
                        System.out.println("2. Exit Dungeon");

                        String input = in.nextLine();

                        while(!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("invalid command");
                            input = in.nextLine();

                        }

                        if(input.equals("1"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("You continue through the thunderdome");
                        }
                        else if(input.equals("2"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("You exit the thunderdome a wiser man, sucessful on your quest");
                            break;
                        }
        }

                System.out.println(" -------------------------- ");
                System.out.println(" ----Thanks for playing----");
                System.out.println(" -------------------------- ");


    }
}
```

Comment: Simply use TextView for displaying text and an EditText for user input, check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html. I also recommend some video tutorials on Android basics: http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/06/android-beginners/

Comment: You are doing a complete mesh above there. And I know you won't even understand a single word from the docs. I suggest you to have a look at these https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcPgdra10Oc&index=5&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you generally use TextView for displaying text, and edit text for text for the user to input.

This is a good link to look at: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

The developer.android training articles are very good, even for a beginner.
Use the xml file in the res/layout folder for your UI stuff. Android Studio even let's you see how your UI will look if you click on the Design tab at the bottom.

Side Note: You'll find it's a lot more fun than System.out.println()

Comment: What if i converted the text to a string and put that in the text view?

Answer (score 1):

**First** in android you need to define a layout. Use:

- [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) to replace inputs of the user (`Scanner`)
- [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to replace outputs to the user (`System.out.println`)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/some_label_text"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/example_input"
    android:hint="@string/some_hint_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

NOTE: Labels, if text is predefined, can have the text in the definition.

**Second** reference your objects into your java app by id like this.

```
EditText exampleInput = (EditText )dialogCarro.findViewById(R.id.example_input);
```

**Third** you will need to add [`Listeners`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941960/how-to-implement-a-listener) to `Button`s or `EditText`s.

Comment: Would I have to replace each system.out.print with a new text view or can it all be done from one

Comment: Depending your requeriments, but in a standart flow with a single one must be enough

Comment: At the moment its just to get it working on android. I got advice on converting the text to a string and putting it into the text view, but that would require multiple text views. If there's a way to display everything in one text view for the moment I suppose that would be a better option.

Comment: Why multiple? Just get `TextView` object like `exampleInput` in my answer and assign it with `setText()` each time you want to put a new text

Comment: each time the user makes a selection, the text just repeats itself(the options 1,2,3 that the user chooses) so if i assign setText() will it display again after the user makes a choice?

Comment: Text will be replaced, but... Whydont you try it and see?