# Displaying text using textView() Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Unsure of how to display text in the xml file, i have code written to output text in the java file but nothing happens when the application is run

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
tv.setText("Welcome to the Dungeon");
```

*

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
android:text="@string/my_text_view"/>
```

Comment: you just create a similar question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891344/displaying-text-in-an-android-studio-project

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#656565"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

And then `setText`

Answer (score 0):

why are you setting text twice in xml and java, just add once as:
but whatever try to provide : fontsize, and gravity(center) of layout, either programmatically or in xml

Comment: I have a load a system.out.println statements in my mainactivity.java im trying to get to display

Comment: ok, then what problem are you facing, print it in string format, after using tv.getText()...... some.

Comment: using the toString() method?

Comment: yes you know that very well, have to convert to string, therefore, i had ..... in place of that