# How to share socket.io connection between Android activities?

Tags: android, node.js, android-activity, socket.io, connection-pooling

In socket.io Android client [example](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) project we read that:

> IO.socket() returns a socket for http://chat.socket.io with the default options. Notice that the method caches the result, so you can always get a same Socket instance for an url from any Activity or Fragment.

So I decided to test that, because number of opened sockets on my server was not equal to number of clients.

I used following server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('- connect event '+socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('- disconnect event from id '+socket.id);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log('. listening on *:3000');
});
```

And developed a very simple Android app, that contains two activities, each opens socket.io connection to the same server address and permits to simply switch between activities.

I start the server and launch the app, this is the output I get.

```
. listening on *:3000
( now I launch the app, opens Activity A )
- connect event 1FIizV3QMdGmnYUQAAAA
( I switch from Activity A to Activity B )
- connect event IzllGFxbpzI5NPNiAAAB
( I switch back from Activity B to Activity A )
- connect event pNt8Yvom5Rih_-01AAAC
- disconnect event from id 1FIizV3QMdGmnYUQAAAA
- disconnect event from id IzllGFxbpzI5NPNiAAAB
```

This simple test suggests that when `onDestroy` event inside the activity I turn off callbacks, socket connection is destroyed, when I restore the activity a new socket connection is opened, but it contradicts `so you can always get a same Socket instance for an url from any Activity or Fragment` stated above, because it seems that new instance is being created.

## Question

It seems that multiple activity model is very common in Android development ( many people suggest it is inefficient to simply change Fragments over and over again ), how to efficiently share a socket connection between such activities, so that server could have the same socket connection for client no matter how many activities it contains?

Option I considered was creating a `BoundService` that would handle all the callbacks and events for socket connection and all Activities could share this service, however I did not find an efficient way of communicating with such service. IPC (inter process communication) in such case could be a huge slow-down, especially if it is based on Intents.

I hope I can get some help on making my app more pro and that it will also be useful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Service` to handle the socket and use a `Binder` to communicate with the service via arbitrary methods instead of via `Intents`. I'm assuming you already know how to work with a started and/or bound Service, if not - [read the guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

You need to override the Service's [`onBind`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind(android.content.Intent)) callback and return a custom subclass of the [`Binder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html) class, which exposes an API for controlling the socket, registering callbacks and the like.

Here's what the code for your `Binder` would probably look like:

```
private final IBinder socketBinder = new SocketBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return socketBinder;
}

public class SocketBinder extends Binder {
    // Now you have access to all your Service's public methods
    public SocketService getService() {
        return SocketService.this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally I fully finished testing your solution. Calling service from Activity was pretty simple, the other way it was a little bit tricky but worked! [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23587641/2398574) helped me a lot with that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi I see this question and I think that is so good, I'am in the same error can you help me, sharing me the code about this solution. please greetings