# How to call finishAffinity() in Service class?

Tags: android, service, activity-finish

I want to clear my app from background `Service` class if a certain scenario is encountered. How to call `finishAffinity()` from `Service` class? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you cannot, just use a bound service pattern and send a callback to your activity so that it can finish by itself

Comment: My requirement is that I want to quit my application if it stays in background for 5 minutes. So I wrote a Service class with timer task. In my timer task, I check whether app is in foreground or background and it is working properly. So if my app is in background for 5 minutes, I want to quit the app. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: quit app f it stays in background? what for? if it is in background, who cares if it is physically killed or not?

Comment: Mine is an augmented reality app. So it consumes lot of memory and battery power and I want to do some optimization. That's why

Comment: memory is not an issue, battery power? so it seems you are not finishing some background jobs in `onPause` / `onStop` / `onDestroy`

Comment: I will check that. But meanwhile can u please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make method in your activity to finish itself using interface like below:

[Calling activity class method from Service class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586031/calling-activity-class-method-from-service-class?rq=1)

And then add below code to finish all your activities in that activity method:

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to cast context to Activity here is a sample for Kotlin API 16+

```
val activity = context as Activity
finishAffinity(activity)
```

Java API 16+

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context; 
finishAffinity(activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert context to activity like this: `(Activity)context` then yon can call finishAffinity like this : `((Activity)context).finishAffinity();`