# Correct way to restart activity after phone call ends

Tags: java, android, service, phone-state-listener

Both of these methods work, but i'm not sure which would be the best code to use so that it works every time for API 17-25.  My app relies on the activity opening after the call ends which I do through a PhoneStateListener.

I have seen both ways recommended, sorry if this is a bad question!

```
Intent restart = mContext.getPackageManager().
            getLaunchIntentForPackage(mContext.getPackageName());
    restart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    restart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(restart);
```

or

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use recreate() method of Activity class to restart Activity instead of this 2 methods

Comment: Ok, how would I call recreate() from inside of my PhoneStateListener?  It is running from a service.  Thank you

Comment: You can do it with Interface check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23587641/5345482