# How to setExtras from Activity to Service?

Tags: android

So I need to send a btDevice defined in one Activity to a Service in the params so I can get it. Here is the code of the service:

```
public class Servicio extends JobService implements ServiceConnection {

private static BluetoothDevice btDevice;
public TemperaturaFragment temperaturaFragment;
private MetaWearBoard mwBoard;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    mJobHandler.sendMessage( Message.obtain( mJobHandler, 1, params ) );
    params.getExtras(btDevice = getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_BT_DEVICE));
    getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, BtleService.class), (ServiceConnection) this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {

    return false;
}
private Handler mJobHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage( Message msg ) {

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                "JobService task running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT )
                .show();
        jobFinished( (JobParameters) msg.obj, false );
        return true;
    }

} );
```

And here is the object that I want to send that is defined in the activity:

```
btDevice= getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_BT_DEVICE);
```

i want to use `builder.setExtras(the object here)` and then in the service `getExtras(get the object)` but the set extras say it is a BluetoothDevice and needs a bundle. Any idea? Thanks for the help.

I put this and doesn't work, because the data is just read, not sent

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Servicio.class.getName())
                    serviceIntent.putExtra(1, getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_BT_DEVICE));
                    getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: Are you try to to pass the device id ? What about using the shared preferences.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass de id, I'm trying to pass the data that it gets, now I see the serialize method, any idea? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `setExtras()` method of `Intent` takes input value as `Bundle` object and `BluetoothDevice`  object is not `Bundle` class object.

you can pass primitive data type , serialized ,`Parcelable` and `ArrayList`  through Bundle and Intent .

**Bound Services**

A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. It allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service, send requests, receive responses, and perform interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does not run in the background indefinitely.

[Bound Service Example In Android](http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/)

And you will find how to call service class method from Activity

[Define an interface your Service will use to communicate events:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586031/calling-activity-class-method-from-service-class)

**EDIT**

you can send data in `Service` through `Intent` like below code:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourService.class.getName())
serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

And you can retrieve that `Intent`  object in `callback` method of `Service` Class called :

When the `Service` is started its `onStartCommand()` method will be called so in this method you can retrieve the value `(UserID)` from the intent object for example

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String userID = intent.getStringExtra("UserID");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**EDIT** **2**

you can also send `BluetoothDevice`  object directly to Intent like below code because its `BluetoothDevice` class implements `Parcelable` interface.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourService.class.getName())
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("btDevice",bluetoothDevice);
serviceIntent.putExtras(bundle);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

And you can retrieve its like below in service class: in `onStartCommand` method

```
BluetoothDevice btDevice = (BluetoothDevice ) bundle.getParcelable("btDevice");
```

Comment: and how can I make it? Is any other method to pass the Device to the service? Or a method to convert Device into Bundle?

Comment: I have no idea how to use Parcelabe and ArrayList with the device, any source or explanation?

Comment: for this you need to create bind service and use binder object to pass any kind of data between service and Activity.

Comment: Any code of example? I'm new and I can't understand it

Comment: But I'm not trying that, I just need the Service to execute the btDevice one time to read the data it has, not to send the data

Comment: So you can get data from btDevice and send that data through Intent and Bundle.

Comment: But how do I do that was my question, because Service can't getIntent()

Comment: in the "123456" what should i put?

Comment: your data which you have obtain from btDevice.

Comment: I will test it now, I was away from the keyboard, that's what i wanted, send it directly

Comment: Wrong at service, `BluetoothDevice btDevice = (BluetoothDevice ) Bundle.getParcelable("btDevice");` non static method get parcelable cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: use non static BluetoothDevice object , remove static from your object decaration.

Comment: sorry, it is now non static and gave the same error