# Android: intent.getExtras().getSerializable(Constants.codiceMainActivity) is null

Tags: java, android, android-service, serializable

I want to start a service from my main activity and pass an object with Serializable. However when I get the object in the Service and I call a method, it is null and I don't know why.
Here is my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable
{
private transient SetVocabulary setVocabulary;
private transient Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setVocabulary = new SetVocabulary();
    findViewById(R.id.imageDizionario).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageGruppi).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageImpara).setOnClickListener(this);

    Intent intentService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceChiusuraApp.class);
    intentService.putExtra(Constants.codiceMainActivity,this);
    Bundle bundleService = new Bundle();
    bundleService.putSerializable(Constants.codiceMainActivity,this);
    intentService.putExtras(bundleService);
    startService(intentService);
}

public SetVocabulary getSetVocabulary()
{
    return setVocabulary;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Here is my Service class:

```
public class ServiceChiusuraApp extends Service
{
MainActivity mainActivity;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    mainActivity = (MainActivity) intent.getExtras().getSerializable(Constants.codiceMainActivity);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = mainActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(Constants.codiceSetString,mainActivity.getSetVocabulary());
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize and pass an `Activity` to a `Service`?

Comment: @Siegmeyer I need to call mainActivity.getSetVocabulary()

Comment: you think you do, but you don't

Comment: @TimCastelijns what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to call `mainActivity.getSetVocabulary()`

In such case you don't want to serialize anything (especially `Activity` which is all kinds of wrong).

Instead, try binding `Activity` to `Service`. This will allow your `Service` and `Activity` to communicate. Please consult this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586031/calling-activity-class-method-from-service-class) on how to call `Activity` class method from `Service`.

Comment: @Tosch an activity is not a regular class. You should not (try to) pass them around. The OS manages their lifecycle

Comment: `Activity` is managed by the operation system, as Tim pointed out. Serialization and consequent deserialization will result in making a copy of the original object, with all the references broken (OS will not by able to manage it anymore). Plus, serialization of an Activity is simply not possible. It's too complex object.

Comment: aah I saw with logs that the references are different as you said. This is why the method returns null!

Answer (score 0):

You want to return data from your `Service` to your `Activity`. There are several ways to do this:

- Bind your `Activity` to your `Service` and using AIDL create a method on your `Service` that returns data.
- Create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` that listens for a specific `Intent` ACTION. In your `Service`, when you want to send data to the `Activity`,create an `Intent` with the appropriate ACTION, add the data as "extras", and call `sendBroadcast()`.