# How to run geofencing app in background?

Tags: android, service, geofencing

I am creating a attendance monitoring app for my campus using geofencing api.Everything else is working smoothly, but I want my app to work in the background.(Similar to a music player). Currently, it works only when the app is open. Here is the Service class code I have used:

```
package com.app.androidkt.geofencing;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;


public class BackgroundService extends Service{
MainActivity main;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    main.isMonitoring = true;
    main.startGeofencing();

main.startLocationMonitor();
      return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //use this method to communicate with your activity
    return null;
}
}
```

And here is the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.app.androidkt.geofencing;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE = 101;

private GoogleMap googleMap;


private GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest;
public GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

public boolean isMonitoring = false;

private MarkerOptions markerOptions;

private Marker currentLocationMarker;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }


}

public void startLocationMonitor() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start location monitor");
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(2000)
            .setFastestInterval(1000)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    try {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                if (currentLocationMarker != null) {
                    currentLocationMarker.remove();
                }
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                markerOptions.title("Current Location");
                currentLocationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                Log.d(TAG, "Location Change Lat Lng " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
            }
        });
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void startGeofencing() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Start geofencing monitoring call");
    pendingIntent = getGeofencePendingIntent();
    geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .addGeofence(getGeofence())
            .build();

    if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google API client not connected");
    } else {
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, geofencingRequest, pendingIntent).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully Geofencing Connected");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to add Geofencing " + status.getStatus());
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    isMonitoring = true;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@NonNull
public Geofence getGeofence() {
    LatLng latLng = Constants.AREA_LANDMARKS.get(Constants.GEOFENCE_ID_STAN_UNI);
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(Constants.GEOFENCE_ID_STAN_UNI)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
            .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build();
}

public PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if (pendingIntent != null) {
        return pendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceRegistrationService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private void stopGeoFencing() {
    pendingIntent = getGeofencePendingIntent();
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(googleApiClient, pendingIntent)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess())
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stop geofencing");
                    else
                        Log.d(TAG, "Not stop geofencing");
                }
            });
    isMonitoring = false;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int response = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);
    if (response != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Play Service Not Available");
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this, response, 1).show();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google play service available");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.reconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.manu_map_activity, menu);
    if (isMonitoring) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_start_monitor).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_stop_monitor).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.startservice).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_start_monitor).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_stop_monitor).setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_start_monitor:
            startGeofencing();
            break;
        case R.id.action_stop_monitor:
            stopGeoFencing();
            break;
        case R.id.startservice:
            startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLng = Constants.AREA_LANDMARKS.get(Constants.GEOFENCE_ID_STAN_UNI);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Stanford University"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17f));

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
            .radius(Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeWidth(4f));

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Api Client Connected");
    isMonitoring = true;
    startGeofencing();
    startLocationMonitor();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Connection Suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    isMonitoring = false;
    Log.e(TAG, "Connection Failed:" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
}
}
```

When I try to run the app in background by clicking the background option i have provided in the app, the app crashes and i get a runtime error saying:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.app.androidkt.geofencing, PID: 24176
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.app.androidkt.geofencing.BackgroundService@52135c5 with Intent { cmp=com.app.androidkt.geofencing/.BackgroundService }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'boolean com.app.androidkt.geofencing.MainActivity.isMonitoring' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3335)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'boolean com.app.androidkt.geofencing.MainActivity.isMonitoring' on a null object reference
                      at com.app.androidkt.geofencing.BackgroundService.onStartCommand(BackgroundService.java:13)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3318)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Please suggest me changes in my code.

Comment: There is a lot of code here. This makes it more difficult to help, since most of it probably doesn't have anything to do with the error and is just distracting. Ideally, you should try to reduce it down to the minimum amount required to reproduce the error (if possible). The actual error seems to be `Attempt to write to field 'boolean com.app.androidkt.geofencing.MainActivity.isMonitoring' on a null object reference`. Maybe you could start by debugging how the that value would/would not end up being `null`, and make your question a bit more precise when you've narrowed that down.

Comment: MainActivity main;
class is not initialized in your BackgroundService.

Comment: and define an interface that your Service will use to communicate with startLocationMonitor.

Answer (score 0):

```
MainActivity main;
```

is not initialized in your BackgroundService.

Try to implement the interface instead accessing the Activity's method like this.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587641/7652758) to implement the interface.