# How to access ImageView using layout in service class?

Tags: android, service, imageview

I want to change the color of ImageView from my Service class. But I don't know how to access ImageView from service class.
This is my layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentStart ="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
        android:src="@drawable/batman_r"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to change the color of ImageView from my Service class. But I don't know how to access ImageView from service class.
I just want to getImageView and get drawable from it and set its Tint to my desirable color.
Please he

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586031/calling-activity-class-method-from-service-class

Comment: Nope, it's not what I want.

Comment: `access ImageView from service class` you should not. Only whatever created the view should access it. What you can do is ask it to change ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't and in fact you can't change UI from `Service`, it's not UI thread... you have to make own custom implementation of [bounding Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services), then send apriopiate message from `Service` to `Activity`, which can make visual changes (in UI thread). [some tutorial in here](https://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/)

another way is to use `LocalBroadcastManager` and send broadcast from `Service`, listen for it in `Activity` (register/unregister receiver in lifecycle), then change UI. [article about in here](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-how-to-send-and-receive-local.html)

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, can you please tell me if the same thing I want to do from Main Activity class, how can I do that. As you can see in my layout I haven't given any id to my ImageView so how can I access it using layout name.

Comment: my app has more than 15 layouts so I haven't given any layout ImageView any id. But I want to change the color of them on users preference and one layout only get visible once for a user. layouts are like design which can be changed on the preference of users.

Comment: you should give unique ids for these `ImageView`s (and other `View`s which you want to access), then use `findViewById` in `Activity`. thats simplest way to get access to inflated views

Comment: can you please look at my this stack question and help me In it. Sorry for bothering you but I really need help now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access your layouts/views from a Service. To achieve this, your activity should have a way to communicate with your service and vice-versa. From the service, you will have to trigger your activity's methods/code to update the color/tint of your image view.

There are several ways to setup communication between your service and activities. A simple way to do this would be by using a BroadcastReceiver in your activity, which can be triggered by your Service by creating a broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

For communication between Service and Activity you can use event bus lib,
Please check below link
[event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)