# public Interface for Android

Tags: android, interface

I need a little help with my Interface. I think that i doesn't understand them at all. 
So i created this interface to notify every classes that implements it when a certain event occurs.

```
public interface OnColorsChangeListener {
    void onColorsChangeListener(ColorsProp colorsProp);
}
```

---

My class that hold the interface:

```
   private OnColorsChangeListener mCallback;

... // other code

    // the event occurs here so i call:
    mCallback.onColorsChangeListener(mProps);
    // but of course here i get an NPE becouse this is undefined in this class.. well,     with some replies here i'll understand better how to use that for reach my point
```

---

The class that implements it:

```
public class ClassTest implements OnColorsChangeListener {

... // other code

@Override
public void onColorsChangeListener(ColorsProp colorsProp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Color changed! " + colorsProp.color);
}
```

i put this in 4/5 classes to be notified in the same time for the color change. I'm quite sure the reason is that I didn't understand very well how them works, so can anyone point me to the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: What is the class that holds the interface supposed to achieve? You might want to read the [Java tutorial on interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: the class that should notify the others is the one with private OnColorsChangeListener mCallback;

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to use a BroadcastReceiver and then have those registered in all places where you want to receive this event simultaneously. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation by example:

You have to instantiate your callback, & it has to be an instance of your class

```
private OnColorsChangeListener mCallback;

mCallback = new ClassTest();


mCallback.onColorsChangeListener(mProps);
```

However if you want multiple callbacks you will need to use the Observer pattern.
Simple example:

```
private List<OnColorsChangeListener> mCallbacks = new ArrayList<OnColorsChangeListener>();

mCallbacks.add(new ClassTest());
mCallbacks.add(new OtherClass());

for(OnColorsChangeListener listener : mCallbacks) {
   listener.onColorsChangeListener(mProps);
}
```

Obviously if you have the class, somewhere else you would not new it up, you would use that reference:

```
mCallbacks.add(mClassTest);
```

---

[Observer Pattern Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Example)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: side note: callbacks and listeners mean slightly different things (also observers). Try not to mix them up like the above. Callbacks are for when 1 thing has finished & you get a callback at the end. Listeners more often can be called after or between an event & multiple times etc

Comment: great, so i definitely need a listener :D

Answer (score 0):

An interface is just a way to group together a bunch of related methods. Implementing this interface then requires you to implement all the methods grouped together by the interface.

The Java Tutorials has a good read on the subject:

[What is an interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Here's a Stackoverflow thread regarding listener interfaces in android:

[How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585247/645270)

In short, you don't use the interface directly since it only specifies which methods implementing classes are supposed to implement.

Comment: well ok... i think I undestand now! so I'm facing the wrong way to achieve my score. Maybe you can point me to a method to notify some classes when an event occurs? (Without using broadcasts)

Comment: @iGio90  Blundell gave a good example of how to do this in your case, as I'm sure you noticed :p