# android: How to wait for listener to complete before continuing?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm using the socialAuth plugin to connect a user to linkdin within my app. I have the connection set up correctly and retrieves data. However, I'm unsure how I can get my main activity to wait until the socialAuthListeners have fired and finished. I know a little about threading but I haven't used it with listeners before. Here's my code:

```
public  class LinkdinAuth {

private static final String TAG = "TEST";
// SocialAuth Components
SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mDialog;

private Context context;
private boolean loggedIn = false;
private Bundle LinkdinData;


public LinkdinAuth(Context C){

    this.context = C;
    LinkdinData = new Bundle();
    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

}       

public void adapterAuthorize(View v){
    adapter.authorize(v.getContext(), Provider.LINKEDIN);
}



private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener
{
   public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
           String providerName = values.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);
           Log.d("Main", "providername = " + providerName);

           mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
           mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
           mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

           //Get profile information
           adapter.getUserProfileAsync(new ProfileDataListener()); 

           // get Job and Education information
           mDialog.show();
           adapter.getCareerAsync(new CareerListener());

           loggedIn = true;
            Log.d("Main", "LOGGED IN = " + loggedIn );
           Toast.makeText(context, providerName + " connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        Log.d("Main", "Dialog Closed by pressing Back Key");        
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("Main", "Cancelled");     
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError e) {
        Log.d("Main", "Error");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}




// To receive the profile response after authentication
private final class ProfileDataListener implements SocialAuthListener<Profile> {

@Override
public void onExecute(String provider, Profile t) {

   Log.d("Sign Up", "Receiving Data");
    mDialog.dismiss();

   Profile profileMap = t;

   LinkdinData.putString("Validated ID",  profileMap.getValidatedId() );
   LinkdinData.putString("First Name", profileMap.getFirstName());
   LinkdinData.putString("Last Name", profileMap.getLastName());
   LinkdinData.putString("Email", profileMap.getEmail());
   LinkdinData.putString("Country", profileMap.getCountry());
   LinkdinData.putString("Language", profileMap.getLanguage());
   LinkdinData.putString("Location", profileMap.getLocation());
   LinkdinData.putString("Profile Image URL", profileMap.getProfileImageURL());
}

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}


private final class CareerListener implements SocialAuthListener<Career> {

    @Override
    public void onExecute(String provider, Career t) {

        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");
        mDialog.dismiss();
        Career careerMap = t;

        //get education
        Log.d("Main", "Education:");
        if(careerMap.getEducations() != null){
            for(Education E: careerMap.getEducations()){
                Log.d("Main",  "School         = " +E.getSchoolName() );
                Log.d("Main",  "Major         = " + E.getFieldOfStudy() );
                Log.d("Main",  "Degree         = " + E.getDegree() );
                Log.d("Main",  "Start Date         = " + E.getStartDate() );
                Log.d("Main",  "End Date         = " + E.getEndDate() );
            }
        }




        Log.d("SignUp", "Career");
        if(careerMap.getPositions() != null){
            for(Position P: careerMap.getPositions()){
                 LinkdinData.putString("Company Name", P.getCompanyName() );
                 LinkdinData.putString("Job Title", P.getTitle() );
                Log.d("Main",  "Industry         = " + P.getIndustry() );
                Log.d("Main",  "Start Date         = " + P.getStartDate() );
                Log.d("Main",  "End Date         = " + P.getEndDate() );

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError e) {
    }
}

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return loggedIn;
}

public Bundle getLinkdinData(){
    return LinkdinData;
}
```

So, as you can see. I have 2 listeners that get data after authorization goes through. And my main activity makes creates an instance, calls the adapterAuthroizeMethod and then if the user logs in a flag is set. Then getLinkedData is called. However I would like it to wait until I know the listeners have fired before calling getlinkdinData. Here's what my Main Activity does after a button press:

```
                L.adapterAuthorize(v);
                loggedInWithLinkdin = L.isLoggedIn();
                Bundle B = L.getLinkdinData();
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), UserRegistration.class);
                i.putExtra("linkdin bundle", B);
                //startActivity(i);
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: The purpose of listeners is to continue without having to wait for something.

Comment: Solution is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android

Comment: How exactly could I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a recommend solution but more of a hack. 
Here is what you can do.

Wrap the aync call around this construct :

```
AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
Global ans; // the return value holder
    try{
        result = someAsyncCall(query, new Thread()); // this new thread is for listener callback
        result.setResultListener(result -> {
            // do something with result.
            ans = result.getAns() ; // set global ans 
            done.set(true);
            synchronized (done) {
                done.notifyAll(); // notify the main thread which is waiting
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        Log(e);
    }
    synchronized (done) {
        while (done.get() == false) {
            done.wait(); // wait here until the listener fires
        }
    }
    return ans; // return global ans
```

Comment: Why is it *"not a recommend solution"*?