# Listen to changes in current month and set Current month as actionBar title

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, calendar, android-actionbar

I am doing an Android app with actionBar tabs. In one tab, there is a fragment with a custom [ExtendedCalendarView](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView).

I can get the current month in the calendar from the fragment every time I want.

What I want is to show the current month as the actionBar title, so I need to detect when the month changes. How I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: Plz show some code. Are you using `ActionBar` or `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: I am using ActionBar. Which code do you need? The default code is that library, I only need something like a listener to detect the month change.

Comment: For setting action bar title: `ActionBar ab = getActionBar();`
    `ab.setTitle("Jan");`

Comment: I know this, but It's not my question. I need to detect when the month has changed

Comment: I can provide some direction - look into the codes ExtendedCalendarView and see how it is implemented : https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView/blob/master/ExtendedCalendarView/src/com/tyczj/extendedcalendarview/ExtendedCalendarView.java ; it has onItemClick and onClick functions and the Class also implements some listeners... try using them or calling them.

Comment: My problem is that I need something like the method "notifyDataSetChanged() of adapters, when you call that, it notifies to the adapter that it has to refresh the listView. 
In this case, I need something that when "refreshCalendar()" is called, notify the fragment to change the actionBar title.

Comment: How does the user change the month? I mean by clicking somewhere on the extended calendar view? On seeing the codes of ExtendedCalendarView i saw that it extends RelativeLayout. And `RelativeLayout` is a subclass of `View`. And `View` has an onClickListener : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html ; So what i am saying is try using the view's onClickListener and inside that listener check if `month value has changed from a previous one`.

Comment: codes of extendedcalendarview: https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView/blob/master/ExtendedCalendarView/src/com/tyczj/extendedcalendarview/ExtendedCalendarView.java

Comment: User changes by swyping, there is a gestureListener that calls the methods of "previous or next month". I think I have to use something like a callback to send the month from the view to the fragment, but I have no idea...

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/994840/3879470 Add a listener and call something like `ml.callback(this, "success");` from previousMonth() or nextMonth().