# How to change the UI elements from another activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to change the TextView that is in  SecondActivity, from MainActivity.Here I am trying to do this through LayoutInflatter and View but unable to do.The TextView in SecondActivity didn't update after the button is clicked.
Here is my MainActivity.java Code:
...

```
package com.example.activity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView tv;
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    //Want to Update the SecondActivity TextView From this MainActivity
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second,null);
    tv=view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //When this Button Clicked then update the textView that is in activity_second.xml
            tv.setText("TextView Changed in SecondActivity");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

...
The SecondActivity xml file where i want to change the TextView:
...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".SecondActivity">
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="Second Activity"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textSize="30sp"
    />
```

...
I need to know how can i did this ? need what Kind of changes in this?
...

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second,null);
    tv=view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

...
Thank You!

Comment: You can't do it. Just pass a value in the intent and init the textview in the oncreate method of 2nd Activity

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to add an extra in the `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "TextView Changed in SecondActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

In the `SecondActivity` you can do:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity_main);
    TextView tv=view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    //...
 
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("key");
        tv.setText(value);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the view from another activity you should use Interfaces callback. What you are doing currently is inflate the view from layout to variable `view`, but the variable `view` is not necessarily attached or used in another activity. Because commonly activity are inflated using `setContentView` method
You can also use broadcast receiver as mentioned from this post.

[Android make callback to an Activity from java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257546/android-make-callback-to-an-activity-from-java-class)