# How can I notify the parent Adapter of a list view of an event from the list view element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

Ok, so I have a list view and it contains some items. The list item has an expiry date. So, the list view contains the item till the date of expiry. After that, there should be a mechanism which can tell the list view to remove that item.

How can I do it? Can I pass a message from the list view item itself or do I have to create some other mechanism which constantly keeps checking for expiry date of all the list items in the list view?

Comment: Thanks, but I got a hint for the answer and think I can take it from there. All I do is from the list item, as soon as the expiry date is over, I get the id of the parent and then tell it to remove the item. Or I can create another function which does that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a tutorial or a course to understand how Java works because there are many ways to do that communication.

You should take a look at this documentation on how to create and use an `interface`: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

You should create a `listener` which is an `interface` and then you implement it on your `activity` or `fragment` and pass it along in the constructor of the listview's adapter.

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585247/3465623