# Accessing FragmentManager in a custom view class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my custom view I have a Java class running a simple game. When the game is finished I'd like to display my `DialogFragment`, but the `getFragmentManager()` method seems to be undefined.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
Finish finish = new Finish();
finish.show(manager, "done");
```

I've tried getting the manager through a `Fragment` obj as:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
FragmentManager manager = fragment.getFragmentManager();
```

But that returns as null. I know it's a new `Fragment` instance, but I'm not sure what value to give it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your `View` should not be directly interacting with `FragmentManager`. Instead, create an interface that your `Activity` can implement, by which your `View` can signal that the game is done, and do the `FragmentTransaction` in the `Activity`'s interface method.

Comment: So something like a static method in the parent view, and call it to signal the game is finished (and proceed with my fragment there)?

Comment: No. You won't be able to access the `FragmentManager` from a `static` method, without some shaky parameter relaying. Use an `interface`.

Comment: Okay I'm just a little fuzy on how to signal. So if I make the interface, and implement it in the Activity, how would my View be able to use that interface to signal the Activity?

Comment: You would pass the `Activity` to the `View` as the interface type, and call the interface method on it when the game is done. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android

Comment: Thanks so much it's working great now!

Answer (score 13):

if your view is attached to an `Activity` then simply you can do

```
((Activity)getContext()).getFragmentManager();
```

**or**

```
((ActivityCompat)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

and to be more safe please make sure you check against of the `View Context` is instance of an `Activity` by doing such:

```
if(getContext() instanceof Activity)// do something
```

and a better solution is, i had rely on a callback between the `View` and the `Activity`.

Comment: Now it's `((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 8):

I use that simple helper method:

```
fun getFragmentManager(context: Context?): FragmentManager? {
    return when (context) {
        is AppCompatActivity -> context.supportFragmentManager
        is ContextThemeWrapper -> getFragmentManager(context.baseContext)
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This won't work for Hilt. In Hilt, the type of the context that is passed to the Fragments' child views is FragmentContextWrapper, Hilt's internal type.

Comment: @BrianOh any work-around here?

Answer (score 0):

For `AndroidX`, you can try:

```
ContextThemeWrapper themeWrapper = (ContextThemeWrapper) getContext();
FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity) themeWrapper.getBaseContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

As recommoned by @k0sh, `instaceof` safety check is recommonded.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this (in Kotlin):

```
if ((context as ContextThemeWrapper).baseContext is AppCompatActivity) {
            //View is attached to an AppCompatActivity
        } else {
            //View is not attached to an AppCompatActivity
        }
}
```

Comment: Reason for negative vote?