# how can i solve this problem with fragmentManager?

Tags: fragmentmanager

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    log("onCreate()");
}
```

I'm trying to create two fragments that communicate with the main activity, but the moment I insert getFragmentManager, the IDE gives me an error in which it says that I imported an incorrect class, when in reality the right class is already present. How can I solve it?

[image: This is my error in code]

(fm = getFragmentManager(); is deprecated and an error in my code)

**Update**: i've changed getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager() but Nothing!!!

Comment: I have the same this problem
[try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56330502)

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `GetFragmentManager();`