# android call function through broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, android-broadcastreceiver

i have a broadcastreceiver.class

```
 public class Myclass extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

i want to call function in broadcastreceiver which is in my activity.please tell me with some code how to made this here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context = this;
    private AudioManager myAudioManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        public void myfunction()
        {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),com.example.faisal.wifiprofile.MainActivity.class);
                p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100000);
            }
        }, 100000);
        }
    }
}
```

here is function name myfunction i want to call this function in broadcastreceiver please tell me good solution or edit my code thanks in advance

Comment: Simply make it static !!

Comment: will you please edit my code i am new in android

Comment: see this question : [How to create our own Listener interface in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class Myclass extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   MainActivity.myfunction();
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context = this;
private AudioManager myAudioManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

    public static void myfunction()
    {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),com.example.faisal.wifiprofile.MainActivity.class);
            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100000);
        }
    }, 100000);
    }
```

}

Comment: when i put function in class it give error can not resolve

Comment: Updated to probably solve your error. If it does not work, post here full error message you get

Comment: public static void myfunction()
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Now in Ringing Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: here is error in MainActivity.this it say make myfunction not static

Comment: @NosheenCh this because you can't access not static fields from static function.
use instead :
Toast.makeText(context, "Now in Ringing Mode", ...
declare variable "static Context context;" in your class, and assign to it "this" in onCreate().
And better update your original code to show it's current state.