# Android communication between Activities without onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

In an App I am currently working on I am facing a problem regarding the communication between Activities.
Basicly I have a UI-Component, which is similar to a `Combobox`. However, the list of the possible values for this component has to be openend in a new `Activity`.
So when you clicked the component, a new `Activity` is opened, using `startActivityForResult`.
When you select the new value, it is put inside a `Bundle` and returned to the previous `Activity`. I then need to use the `onActivityResult`-method to get the selected value and set it to the component.
That means, that every `Activity` that uses this component needs to override `onActivityResult` and refresh the component with the new value.
What I want instead is, that the component takes care about all this stuff and you only have to register a `Listener`, just like you do it for a `TextView` and similar components.
But at the moment I just can't find a good way to do that, as the communication is tightly bound to the `Activity` and I just can't get the result of the `Activity` outside the `onActivityResult`.
Does anyone know a good solution for this problem?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I can't see, how this should solve my issue... My problem is, that the `Activity` needs to return a result (the selected value), which I would like to receive without using `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you need to start a new activity in order to get the value?

Comment: Yes. The values are `Reference`s to another table. So there might be many objects. I offer a method to filter those references by different fields or search them. So this `Activity` could get pretty complex and therefore I want it to be in a sepparate `Activity`, not in a dialog.

Comment: You can try using broadcasts :P

Comment: Use `interface` or `broadcast` receiver.

Comment: `Broadcast`s really could do the job, I'll try that one out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [BroadCastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)?

Basically you send a *broadcast* and every activity that is registered to receive that broadcast will receive that broadcast will receive the message in `onReceive`

First of all **declare in the manifesto** what you are going to listen for, something like:

```
   <receiver android:name=".TestBroadCast”>
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="io.test.TEST"/>
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Than simply **extend BroadCastReceiver**

```
public class TestBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //TODO: Handle the Intent received.

}
```

Example of how to **send** a broadcast:

```
   public static final String INTENT_ACTION = "io.test.TEST";
   public static final String INTENT_EXTRA  = "someData";

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION);
   intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA,"test");
   sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And you will get the Intent and than you can handle it as you wish :)!

### UPDATE ~ Registering from code instead of manifesto

To avoid registering the service from the Manifesto you can do it from the code, with a code similar to the following listing:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("io.test.TEST");
TestBroadCastReceiver mReceiver = new TestBroadCastReceiver();
context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

P.S.
I suggest you using [LocalBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) if you don't need other applications to be able to send results insted of the common BroadcastReceiver for **security reasons**

Comment: I'll try to go with `BroadCastReceiver`. However, I won't register it in the `Manifest`, but in the source code of the component. That way, the `Activity` does not need to know anything about it.

Comment: @Springrbua yes that's even better, I'll update the question to make it complete :)

Comment: @Springrbua I understand that you know how to the register from code, but I have updated the answer so someone who does not can find it :) Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer.  
In my case I need to register it in the sourcecode, because the name of the `BraodCast` is dynamic. I could have multiple components, which allow you to choose different `Reference`s (for example a `Delivery address` and a `Billing address`). The component, which is responsible for the `Delivery address` should ofc only get that `BraodCast`. Therefore I have an "IntentFilterPrefix" like "io.test.TEST." as well as a suffix which might be "delivery" or "billing".

Comment: I just wanted to let you know, that this solution works perfectly in my case. The component just needs to register itself as a `BroadcastReceiver` and open the `ChooserActivity` on click. The `ChooserActivity` then just needs to send a `Broadcast`, containing the selected `Reference`. This way, my component handles everything and can inform it's `Listener`s about changes.

Comment: @Springrbua I am very glad that you found that helpful :)!

Answer (score 2):

Solution to this- use `EventBus` and post sticky event on it. By doing so you don't have to override `onActivityResult`.

The workflow will be as following: 
- Create event object with your data 
- Remove all sticky events of the same type from the Bus
- post new values by `.sendSticky()` method.

That event will be around until something remove it from the bus
- start another activity
- in this activity override method, subscribing to that event type, in it:
 a) take and process event with your argument
 b) remove it from the bus
- subscribe to the bus (second Activity) in `onResume()` method
- unsubscribe from the bus in `.onPause()` method

The point is, that this allow you to seamlessly handle lifecycle of second Activity, and you can subscribe/unsubscribe to the bus in base class

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Observer Design Pattern, the better implementation of that are [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and a Library which implement event bus design [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Alex Shutov was right Try this
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Comment: I would like to avoid using external libraries, as long as possible. However, if i can't find another method, I''ll come back to this. Thanks!

Comment: ohk no Problem 
try broadcastreceiver

Comment: If you know, how to solve this issue using an `Interface`, please update your answer. At the moment I can't see, how an `Interface` would help me. The communication still would need to go from one activity to the other, which is the step I would like to avoid.

Comment: ohk just a minute

Comment: hello try this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android

Comment: I still can't see, how this could help me in my case. As I switch `Activity`, I don't have a reference to my component anymore, so I can't notify it. The only way would be to pass my component (which is a `View`) to the new `Activity` in a `Bundle`. However, most `View`s should generally not be passed and most of them can't even be serialized (no parameterless constructor)...

Answer (score 0):

Use EventBus here is the link https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
only 3 steps and yes it is 3rd PartyLibrary. its very light should not affect your app size as well

Answer (score 0):

Generally for such scenario I will keep the data in Main Activity as static data and use and update them in other activities.

For example you can declare and populate these 2 variables in Main Activity (i.e. MainActivity)

`public static  ArrayList arrayList ;`

`public static  SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray ;`

now all other activities while populating list values, they can populate from array list using  name  MainActivity.arrayList. When user select or unselect a value only sparseBooleanArray will be updated with a boolean value.

while populating values first time in arrayList and sparseBooleanArray , ensure to use same index so they will be in sync

`arrayList.add(1,"List Item 1") ;`

`sparseBooleanArray.put(1,false ) ; // represent selected value for List Item 1`

In case you have plan to use this functionality for multiple activities, arraylist will remain same, however there will be one SparseBooleanArray for each activity to store activity wise selected values.

Comment: That's not very good style, because it it breaks incapsulation