# Listening for activity button clicks from inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, listener

I've just started learning about fragments and I have an activity which is 1000+ lines of code that I've converted to a fragment.

I'm wondering if there is any easy way to allow my fragment to listen to buttons that reside in the XML of it's parent activity. I tried just adding a regular listener in the fragment's `onCreateView` with the ID of the buttons but it's (expectedly) giving me a null pointer exception.

I do know of the `OnSearchClickListener` method of doing this but it would probably take a good many hours of manual refactoring to achieve what I need (at least from what I can tell about its usage, I'd be happy to be wrong), so I was wondering if anyone knows of any other method to get this done in a non-repetitive way.

Comment: implement interface for the communication between activity and fragments. Refer: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Comment: You can achieve this using an Interface. Make your Fragment implement the interface and overide the interface method to perform your desired function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to get a reference of view in activity this way:

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_in_activity);
```

Then add listener:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform some action
    }
})
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to my question, although I learned about other forms of activity-fragment communication (interfaces) from the other answers (thank you all).

Comment: How to acheive that on Xamarin?

Answer (score 4):

In Fragment make like this..

```
public class Myfragment extends Fragment {

    public interface Callback {
        public void onButtonClicked(View radiobtn);
    }

    private Callback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity ac) {
        super.onAttach(ac);
        callback = (Callback) ac;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        callback = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    radiobtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onButtonClicked(view);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In Activity do like this...

```
public class Myfragment extends Activity implements MyFragment.Callback{

    public void onButtonClicked(View btn) {
        // The radiobutton in MyFragment has been clicked
        myButton.setEnabled(true); // or something like this.
    }
}
```

Comment: its question for get click from activity to fragment Not fragment to Activity

Answer (score 3):

Define an interface called like `ClickListenerOnActivity` contains a method named `onClickInActivity(View v)` and implement that in fragment. When click the button in activity call this method of the interface.

You can view this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585099/1595442) to see how to implement an interface.

Answer (score 2):

Despite Emre Akturk's answer isn't wrong, but it is not the best practice, hence you may attach your `Fragment` to another `Activity` and after that, that `Activity` may not have that `View`. So, the best way is using an `interface`. Make your `Fragment` implements your desired interface and then in `onClickListener` of your `Button`, call the interface of that `Fragment`.