# How to create Refresh fragment to fragment with button click (showing data in listview adapter)

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

i have create two Fragment with two TAB one for Register another one for Showing data,When i click the save button in fragment one,the data showing in second fragment(The second fragment i'm using listview Adapter)List view

Comment: Is the fragments are on same screen?

Comment: yes, i have using 2 tab Register and Show

Comment: So when you click register button on fragment first you want to update listview in fragment second. Is this the doubt?

Comment: yes,it's correct

Comment: You can use listener(i.e Interface) or local BroadCastReceiver to get update on second fragment

Comment: please i'm new in android can you post the sample code

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: public class Visitorallow extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{Connection con=connectionClass.CONN();
                if(con==null){ Z="Error in Connection with SQL Server";
                } else {String query="Update app_Registration set FlatOwner='"+1+"' where Id='"+RegIdno+"'"; PreparedStatement preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement(query);preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); Z="Update Successfully";isSuccess=true; }  }catch(Exception ex){ isSuccess=false;Z="Exception"; } return Z; }

Comment: https://github.com/muditsen/eventer try using the library for communication between activity and fragments or between 2 fragments.

Answer (score 0):

See [communication between two fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

More Easy [How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android)

or

See [localBroadcastReciever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Even you can use EventBus library for application components communication

Check https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus