# How to wait Activity A wait for Activity B result without startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I am working on library project. My project contains all Java file but I am include one activity for web view. When I call from Java class to open web view then I want return result back to Java class. What should I do. I try startActivityForResult
but this solution not work because onActivityResult not override in simple Java class.
My code for startActivityForResult

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
Intent i = new Intent(activity, WebViewAunthen.class);
i.putExtra("smartRouteMap", (Serializable) SmartPayment.res);
activity.startActivityForResult(i, 1);`
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==1)
    {

    }
```

Comment: use [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) to solve this

Comment: Use custom listeners to solve this

Comment: You need to create interfaces
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android