# How can I return a value from a function that uses json response?

Tags: java, android, json

I have implemented function to get the restaurant area minimum order. In check_minimum_order() function, I have got desired result from the response. The value is rest_area_min_order = 10. Now, I want to pass the value which I received through JSON to the next function So that I can do calculation part.

Here is the code of **check_minimum_order()**

```
    private void check_minimum_order(String restaurant_id)
{
    try
    {
        String url;
        if(appPrefs.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("ar"))
            url = LinksConstants.BASE_URL
                    + LinksConstants.CHECK_MINIMUM_ORDER;
        else
            url = LinksConstants.BASE_URL
                    + LinksConstants.CHECK_MINIMUM_ORDER;

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        params.put("restaurant_id", restaurant_id);
        params.put("area_id", city_id);

        NetworkRestClient.post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();

                progressActivity.showLoading();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

                try
                {
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        rest_area_min_order = response.getString("restaurant_area_min_order");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    GSLogger.e(ex);
                    showError();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String errorResponse, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, errorResponse, throwable);

                showError();

                if(AppConstants.DEBUG_MODE)
                    showToast(errorResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);

                showError();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GSLogger.e(ex);
        showError();
    }
}
```

Now, the above check_minimum_order() function gave me the value of rest_area_min_order as 10. Now, I want to use this rest_area_min_order in another function. Here is the code: `

```
            check_minimum_order(restaurant_id);

            HashMap<String, Object> items_hash = (HashMap<String, Object>) rest_cart_hash.get(restaurant.getId());

            items_hash.put("delivery_pickup_time", time);
            items_hash.put("pickup_address_id", pickup_id);
            items_hash.put("payment_method_id", payment_id);
            items_hash.put("delivery_pickup", delivery_pickup);
            items_hash.put("selected_user_address_id", user_address_id);
            items_hash.put("rest_area_min_order", rest_area_min_order);

            restaurantList.add(items_hash);

            String rest_min_order = (String) items_hash.get("rest_min_order");
            String rest_subtotal = (String) items_hash.get("rest_subtotal");
            String rest_area_min_order = (String) items_hash.get("rest_area_min_order");

            boolean isError = isValidMinOrderAmount(rest_min_order, rest_subtotal, rest_area_min_order);`
```

Comment: put that code under the `rest_area_min_order`

Comment: @OussemaAroua I did not get you. Can you explain?

Comment: put the function code inside the onSuccess under                        rest_area_min_order = response.getString("restaurant_area_min_order");

Comment: @OussemaAroua The whole function becomes likes this https://paste.ofcode.org/Tzp4pVQdhLqhTEM6zSYejP

Comment: check this way : https://paste.ofcode.org/3gmKZ5kvQirW3q3kUMABQB

Comment: @OussemaAroua Let me check with this way. Looks promising.

Comment: cannot resolve method mFunction()

Comment: Kindly check this image. http://imgur.com/a/8puSp

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/kAXUTnfWmwjHX3qFZ6RB7n , it's a matter of structurer my fault sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your `onSuccess` function return `void` so you cannot return anything. You can simply call another function in `onSuccess` (For example `setMinimumOrder(int pMinimumOrder)`) which will take `rest_area_min_order` as a input and you can perform rest of the things as per your requirement.

Comment: I just updated my code. Can you check this link? https://paste.ofcode.org/Tzp4pVQdhLqhTEM6zSYejP

Comment: @Jacky I have just edited your code. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I know, there are two options to achieve this.

1) Put the code to be executed, directly in **onSuccess** after getting the value of **rest_area_min_order**. Or you can create a separate method for that.

2) Using Interface to pass value.

I prefer the first option which is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you have to do some calculation after getting web service response. If the rest of calculation needs to done in same class then call that method after getting response

```
if (response != null)
{
  rest_area_min_order = response.getString("restaurant_area_min_order");
   doPostCalculations(rest_area_min_order);
}
```

If check_minimum_order() method is in Network class and you are calling this method from another class (eg: activity), then you can communicate back to activity(or the class that called the method) using interface on getting the response.

Here is a sample interface that you can use.

```
public interface ApiListener {
   void onSuccess(JSONObject response);
   void onFailure();
}
```

Please have a look at this post for getting more idea about interface - [How to create our own Listener interface in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994840/how-to-create-our-own-listener-interface-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that in your check_minimum_order method you post your networking to another thread if you wan to do some work with the result returned from network then you must call it in on success after the result is really fetched.